# Easiest way to delete a column?

Tags: tables, columns

I have a set of 10 tables and each has an extra column that I don't want. Specifically, these tables are descriptions of database tables exported by phpMyAdmin, and they all have a "MIME" column that I would like to remove. Is there a way to do this other than using string manipulation / find and replace?

I have tried setting the column to `p{0in}`, but the column title still remains.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccHc}
one & two & hide & three\\
1 & 2 & H & 3
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
one & two & three\\
1 & 2 &  3
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The second tabular is there to show that the result is the same. Basically, we set a column without intercolumn space, and its content is swallowed by `\setbox0=\hbox{<entry>}`

For the last column you need to fix the last padding, use, for instance

```
\begin{tabular}{ccH@{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}
```

Example code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ccHc}
one & two & hide & three\\
1 & 2 & H & 3
\end{tabular}}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
one & two & three\\
1 & 2 &  3
\end{tabular}}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ccH@{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}
one & two & hide \\
1 & 2 & H
\end{tabular}}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ccZ}
one & two & hide \\
1 & 2 & H
\end{tabular}}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{cc}
one & two \\
1 & 2
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very cool!

Comment: You can write it shorter by using the `lrbox` environment, which is the environment form of `\sbox` (which is the LaTeX form of the plain `\setbox`): 

`\newcolumntype{H}{>{\lrbox0}c<{\endlrbox}@{}}`.

@Alan might find this even cooler ;-)

Comment: This doesn't entirely erase the column. If it's only the end and there's a cell or row colour, it will show up: `\newcolumntype{H}{>\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\cellcolor{white}}c<{\egroup}@{}}`

Comment: If it's used in the last column the spacing isn't correct (two `\tabcolsep`s instead of one). The same is true for every solution provided in this thread that work in the last column.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for the prompt, I added the needed workaround

Answer (score 39):

The solution of egreg is good. It typesets the cell content in a box which is then discarded. All code in the cell is executed and typeset. There are also two alternatives which I list here for the sake of completeness.

First you can use the `collcell` package to collect the cell content and then feed it to a macro which simply discards it. The `\@gobble` macro does that. This method doesn't execute or typeset the cell content but needs to scan every token. It might be faster or slower than the use of a box dependent on the content.

Another method is to insert a macro which reads everything till the next `\unskip` which is inserted after each cell except the very last column of a row. There the `\unskip` is inside `\\` and won't be seen by the macro.
This method is the fastest and doesn't execute, typeset or check the cell content beside the argument scanning of the TeX parser.

For small cells the speed difference should be not important.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{collcell}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\collectcell\@gobble}c<{\endcollectcell}@{}}
\makeatother
% Fastest. Does not work in the last column.
\def\eatcell#1\unskip{}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\eatcell}c@{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccGc}
one & two & hide & three\\
1 & 2 & H & 3
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccEc}
one & two & hide & three\\
1 & 2 & H & 3
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
one & two & three\\
1 & 2 &  3
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice; I should remember the collcell package.

Comment: Is the solution that doesn't work in the last column, but is faster, really a solution? :-) When I first started programming I was told the following story by my boss: Some engineers and some computer scientists are asked to solve a problem. The engineers say "Our program is 10000 lines of FORTRAN that takes 8 hours to run"; the computer scientists say "Ours is much better, it's 2000 lines of LISP and takes an hour to run.  But it sill has a few bugs...."

Comment: @Alan: If it would be a satisfying solution I wouldn't had spend all the time coding the `collcell` package :-) It doesn't has a bug, just two limitations. The not-in-the-last-column is the first and the second I forgot to mention is that the cell must not contain an `\unskip` outside `{ }`.

Answer (score 3):

Or in short:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\iffalse}c<{\fi}@{}}
```

Can be made visible by changing the column type or by changing `\iffalse` into `\iftrue`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the last column.

Answer (score 0):

An `tabularray` example in case a `tabularray` equivalence is called for (actually already wanted once in [`lvjr/tabularray#451`](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/451)).

Note the similarly defined `H` column type doesn't work with `vlines` inner key.

Theoretically `tabularray` could do better. As the table body (aka. environment content) is split and then stored in a per-cell basis before typesetting, there's indeed an internal state at that time one can truly manipulate the table structurally. But then all references to row and column numbers are suffering from a mapping.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewColumnType{H}{Q[cmd={\setbox0=\vbox}, colsep=0pt]}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\rulewidth}{3pt} % enlarge \rulewidth to emphasis the difference

\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vline{1,Z},
    colspec={lHl}
}
  One & Hide & Two \\
  One & XXXX & Two \\
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vline{1,Z},
    colspec={ll}
}
  One & Two \\
  One & Two \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]