# How to make a table column disappear?

Tags: tables, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to delete a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column)

I have many table in my document, and I have decided I don't want one of their columns to appear in the output.  I don't want to just remove the columns -- the tables are long and fiddly to edit, I might change my mind and want the column back, etc.  So I am trying to come up with a new column specifier (using the `array` package) that discards a column entirely, making the table appear as if said column was not in the source code ("commented out," as it were).  Here's an example document, with a couple ideas I've tried with no success:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\def\FooGobble#1\EndGobble{}

% leaves extra blank space between the columns
%\newcolumntype{X}{>{\FooGobble}l<{\EndGobble}}

% continues to typeset SURPRISE
%\newcolumntype{X}{p{0in}}

% still leaves extra space
\newcolumntype{X}{>{\FooGobble}p{0in}<{\EndGobble}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lXl}
    first col & SURPRISE & second col \\
\end{tabular}

should appear the same as:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    first col & second col \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of very nice solutions to an identical question here: Easiest way to delete a column?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/2693

Comment: Ack, I didn't think to use the word "delete" when I was searching for similar questions.  :/