# Macro limited in scope to the tabular cell in which it is invoked?

Tags: tables, macros, delimiters

How do I reuse cell delimiter of a `tabular` environment (usually ampersand) for delimiting a macro parameter?

Like this (which unfortunately doesn't work):

```
\def\mymacro#1&{#1}
```

...

```
\begin{tabular}
Hello & \mymacro out & there \\
\end{tabular}
```

where `\mymacro` shall only apply to *out*.

I'd rather not use curly braces in this particular case to delimit the parameter value.

Also, I should mention that a space won't work either as there might be spaces in the parameter value as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your macro has only one argument. What is there to delimit? What role is the ampersand supposed to play in this?

Comment: I see. I'd like the macro to apply for the whole cell content of a tabular which it is in without having to use curly braces surrounding that content.

Comment: Now I understand. I think you should add that clarification in your question.

Comment: @Jubobs, thanks for editing the question correspondingly.

Comment: This might be related to your problem: [Easiest way to delete a column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/)

Answer (score 5):

The exact rules of how macro expansion interacts with table scanning are somewhat arcane but in this instance you can do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
```

or a version that works even if not the first token in the cell.

[image]

```
\def\mymacro#1&{\fbox{#1\unskip}&}


\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\def\mymacro{\relax\mymacrox}
\def\mymacrox#1\unskip{\fbox{#1\unskip}}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Hello &aaa \mymacro out & there \\
Hello &\mymacro out & there \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Hello & \mymacro out & there \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This only works if `\mymacro` is the first (non-space) token in the cell.  In general, the OP is right that it will break.

Comment: Yeah, it will suffice for now. If there's another more flexible solution that does not require to be the first non-space token, as mentioned by @BrunoLeFloch, I'll be grateful if someone could explain that as well.

Comment: @HendrikWiese you can make more general versions or, simpler in some ways versions that work with the `>{\myfoo}c<{\endmyfoo}` syntax of array package, but they all have quirks and edge cases...

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch updated with alternative version that works mid cell.

Comment: @HendrikWiese updated