# Hiding a column with colored cells

Tags: tables, colortbl

I want to use the column type described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16607/21841) to hide certain columns in a table. The table occurs multiple times throughout the document, always with different columns hidden. Some of the cells are highlighted using the `colortbl` package, and this is what appears to cause a problem:

[image: problem]

It appears that the colored cells are somehow "leaking" from the hidden cells into the following cells. What can I do to prevent this? I want the background color of the hidden cells disappear completely - I do not want it to appear even partially in the following cells.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\gc}{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}

\newcommand{\tablebody}{%
      foo &     bar & \gc boo &     baz &     faa \\
      bar & \gc boo &     baz & \gc faa &     foo \\
  \gc boo &     baz &     faa &     foo & \gc bar \\
      baz & \gc faa &     foo & \gc bar &     boo \\
      faa &     foo & \gc bar &     boo &     baz %
}

\begin{document}

\section*{all columns visible}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{center column hidden}

\begin{tabular}{ccHcc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{middle columns hidden}

\begin{tabular}{cHcHc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{outer columns hidden}

\begin{tabular}{HcccH}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the issue isn't that columns are disappearing (i.e., that is purposeful), but that when you attempt to hide them, they leave behind residual color?  Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Exactly.

Comment: Setting `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` eliminates it, which is a start, but then you need to figure out a way to get the horizontal buffer space back in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\makeatletter
\def\zz{\aftergroup\zzz}
\def\zzz\begingroup#1\endgroup
    {\global\let\CT@do@color\relax\global\let\CT@cell@color\relax}
\newcommand{\gc}{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}
\newcolumntype{H}
   {>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\bgroup}c<{\egroup\egroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\zz}@{}}

\newcommand{\tablebody}{%
      foo &     bar & \gc boo &     baz &     faa \\
      bar & \gc boo &     baz & \gc faa &     foo \\
  \gc boo &     baz &     faa &     foo & \gc bar \\
      baz & \gc faa &     foo & \gc bar &     boo \\
      faa &     foo & \gc bar &     boo &     baz %
}

\begin{document}

\section*{all columns visible}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{center column hidden}

\begin{tabular}{ccHcc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{middle columns hidden}

\begin{tabular}{cHcHc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{outer columns hidden}

\begin{tabular}{HcccH}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I probably didn't succeed in making my aim clear enough. I want the background color of the hidden cells disappear completely, not stretched out across the following (totally unrelated) cells.

Comment: @vwegert that was the intention here;-) I had to dash out for a bit just as I was posting, I'll have a look what this does.

Comment: @vwege sorry, fixed now I hopert

Comment: Brilliant - I just wish I knew how those incantations actually work… :-)

Comment: @vwegert they just disable colortbl's color panel for the hidden cell (using a not exactly advertised interface, but it is my code I'm disabling so I think I'm allowed:-)

Comment: Well, \zzz is a good suggestion - as in getting some sleep. However, I'll pose another table-related question first…

Answer (score 2):

This is, I hope, an improvement over my earlier attempt.  To eliminate the residual color, I had to set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`.  I then used `@{\extracolsep{1ex}}` to add column gap back in.  The only downside is that the extracolsep will not be colored in a cell, but that may be a workable solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\let\svtabcolsep\tabcolsep
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\newcommand{\gc}{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}

\newcommand{\tablebody}{%
      foo &     bar & \gc boo &     baz &     faa \\
      bar & \gc boo &     baz & \gc faa-extra-extra long &     foo \\
  \gc boo &     baz &     faa &     foo & \gc bar \\
      baz & \gc faa &     foo & \gc bar &     boo \\
      faa &     foo-extra long & \gc bar &     boo &     baz %
}

\begin{document}

\section*{all columns visible}

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{1ex}}ccccc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{center column hidden}

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{1ex}}ccHcc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{middle columns hidden}

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{1ex}}cHcHc}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\section*{outer columns hidden}

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{1ex}}HcccH}
  \tablebody
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work for me - the grayed out cells are empty in my document. I need the entire cell grayed out, and the colorbox only colors part of the cell.

Comment: @vwegert  OK, I'll delete this answer, but think further upon it.

Comment: @vwegert  Although, let me ask one last question... are there any added constraints, like all columns end up being the same width, for example, because of the nature of the inputs. (It sort of looks that way in your example, but that may be coincidence).

Comment: The identical width is a coincidence - my table is far more complex. http://imagebin.org/275170 is a screenshot of the spreadsheet file I'm trying to replace.

Comment: @vwegert  Understood.  Perhaps you could add that pointer to your question.

Comment: @vwegert Please see totally revised answer.