# How to delete a column from a table?

Tags: tables

I have this table:
[image]

On the far left there is a column labeled index. I want to remove this column but when I try the table will no longer compile. Any help would be appreciated! Also sorry I'm not sure how to post code on this site yet!

This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|l| c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Jaro-Winkler} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF (3-gram)} \\ \hline
    % & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Soft TF-IDFT} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Soft TF-IDFT (3-gram)} \\ \hline

  Index  & {$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}      &{$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}
    & {$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}  \\ \hline


   1 &0 &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0  &0.2789 &37.68  &0.7439     &0  &0.2395 &32.81  &0.7201 \\ \hline %Row 1

   2 &0.2   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.2    &0.9583 &463.18 &0.9003  &0.2   &0.8483 &271.59  &0.8872 \\ \hline %Row 2

   3 &0.4   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.4    &0.9907 &445.94 &0.9318  &0.4   &0.9861 &484.57  &0.9159 \\ \hline %Row 3

  4  &0.6   &0.0034 &0.5916 &0.4676  &0.6   &0.9976 &374.23 &0.9299 &0.6    &0.9942 &410.28 &0.9308 \\ \hline %Row 4

   5 &0.8   &0.1944 &16.18  &0.6317 &0.8    &0.9976 &283.43 &0.9285 &0.8    &0.9976 &326.86 &0.9291 \\ \hline %Row 5

   6 &1 &0.9629 &207.14 &0.9074     &1  &0.9976 &33.29  &0.9266     &1  &0.9976 &156.52 &0.9273 \\ \hline %Row 6

  A  &0.8942    &0.9548 &193.84 &0.9060 &0.5522 &0.9837 &470.70 &0.9156 &0.5943 &0.9814 &472.90  &0.9155 \\ \hline %Row 7

\end{tabular}}

\end{table}
```

Comment: To highlight code, just select it and click the button marked `{}`. Blocks are indented by four spaces, inline code delimited by backticks (`\``).

Comment: If you wish to remove a column, you don't have to do this physically. You can let LaTeX remove it for you. Follow the instructions in [Easiest way to delete a column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/5764)

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention which error(s) you're getting, but removing the information of the first column should be straightforward to accomplish.

You shouldn't use math mode to put the words in the second header row in italics; use `\textit` instead. The intra-word spacing will be greatly improved.

Separately, as is shown in the second table below, you may want to consider decluttering the table by getting rid of all vertical lines and most of the horizontal lines, as well as (for the horizontal lines that remain) get better spacing than is is possible with just `\hline`: the `\booktabs` package offers the commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule` (with trimming options), and `\bottomrule` for just this purpose. Finally, it may be a good idea to align the numbers on their decimal signs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Jaro-Winkler} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF (3-gram)} \\ 
\hline
\textit{Threshold} & \textit{Purity} & \textit{Zrand} & \textit{NMI} & 
\textit{Threshold} & \textit{Purity} & \textit{Zrand} & \textit{NMI} & 
\textit{Threshold} & \textit{Purity} & \textit{Zrand} & \textit{NMI}  \\  \hline
0 &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0  &0.2789 &37.68  &0.7439     &0  &0.2395 &32.81  &0.7201 \\ \hline %Row 1

0.2   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.2    &0.9583 &463.18 &0.9003  &0.2   &0.8483 &271.59  &0.8872 \\ \hline %Row 2

0.4   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.4    &0.9907 &445.94 &0.9318  &0.4   &0.9861 &484.57  &0.9159 \\ \hline %Row 3

0.6   &0.0034 &0.5916 &0.4676  &0.6   &0.9976 &374.23 &0.9299 &0.6    &0.9942 &410.28 &0.9308 \\ \hline %Row 4

0.8   &0.1944 &16.18  &0.6317 &0.8    &0.9976 &283.43 &0.9285 &0.8    &0.9976 &326.86 &0.9291 \\ \hline %Row 5

1 &0.9629 &207.14 &0.9074     &1  &0.9976 &33.29  &0.9266     &1  &0.9976 &156.52 &0.9273 \\ \hline %Row 6

0.8942    &0.9548 &193.84 &0.9060 &0.5522 &0.9837 &470.70 &0.9156 &0.5943 &0.9814 &472.90  &0.9155 \\ \hline %Row 7

\end{tabular}}

\bigskip

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{@{} d{1.4}cd{3.4}c *{2}{d{1.4}cd{3.2}c} @{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{Jaro-Winkler} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{TF-IDF} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{TF-IDF (3-gram)} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(r){5-8} \cmidrule{9-12}
\mc{\textit{Threshold}} &  \mc{\textit{Purity}} &  \mc{\textit{Zrand}} &  \mc{\textit{NMI}} &  
\mc{\textit{Threshold}} &  \mc{\textit{Purity}} &  \mc{\textit{Zrand}} &  \mc{\textit{NMI}} &  
\mc{\textit{Threshold}} &  \mc{\textit{Purity}} &  \mc{\textit{Zrand}} &  \mc{\textit{NMI}}  \\  
\midrule
0 &0.0023 &\mc{NaN}    &0.4670     &0  &0.2789 &37.68  &0.7439     &0  &0.2395 &32.81  &0.7201 \\  %Row 1

0.2   &0.0023 &\mc{NaN}    &0.4670     &0.2    &0.9583 &463.18 &0.9003  &0.2   &0.8483 &271.59  &0.8872 \\ %Row 2

0.4   &0.0023 &\mc{NaN}    &0.4670     &0.4    &0.9907 &445.94 &0.9318  &0.4   &0.9861 &484.57  &0.9159 \\ %Row 3

0.6   &0.0034 &0.5916 &0.4676  &0.6   &0.9976 &374.23 &0.9299 &0.6    &0.9942 &410.28 &0.9308 \\ %Row 4

0.8   &0.1944 &16.18  &0.6317 &0.8    &0.9976 &283.43 &0.9285 &0.8    &0.9976 &326.86 &0.9291 \\ %Row 5

1 &0.9629 &207.14 &0.9074     &1  &0.9976 &33.29  &0.9266     &1  &0.9976 &156.52 &0.9273 \\ %Row 6

0.8942    &0.9548 &193.84 &0.9060 &0.5522 &0.9837 &470.70 &0.9156 &0.5943 &0.9814 &472.90  &0.9155 \\ %Row 7 
\bottomrule 

\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the modified code to remove the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Jaro-Winkler} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF (3-gram)} \\ \hline
   % & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Soft TF-IDFT} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Soft TF-IDFT (3-gram)} \\ \hline

   {$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}      &{$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}
   & {$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}  \\ \hline


   0 &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0  &0.2789 &37.68  &0.7439     &0  &0.2395 &32.81  &0.7201 \\ \hline %Row 1

   0.2   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.2    &0.9583 &463.18 &0.9003  &0.2   &0.8483 &271.59  &0.8872 \\ \hline %Row 2

   0.4   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.4    &0.9907 &445.94 &0.9318  &0.4   &0.9861 &484.57  &0.9159 \\ \hline %Row 3

   0.6   &0.0034 &0.5916 &0.4676  &0.6   &0.9976 &374.23 &0.9299 &0.6    &0.9942 &410.28 &0.9308 \\ \hline %Row 4

   0.8   &0.1944 &16.18  &0.6317 &0.8    &0.9976 &283.43 &0.9285 &0.8    &0.9976 &326.86 &0.9291 \\ \hline %Row 5

   1 &0.9629 &207.14 &0.9074     &1  &0.9976 &33.29  &0.9266     &1  &0.9976 &156.52 &0.9273 \\ \hline %Row 6

   0.8942    &0.9548 &193.84 &0.9060 &0.5522 &0.9837 &470.70 &0.9156 &0.5943 &0.9814 &472.90  &0.9155 \\ \hline %Row 7

\end{tabular}}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Some remarks:

1. I would use the specifier `h` instead of `H` to keep the `table` "here", that is I would use

   ```
   \begin{table}[h]
   ```
2. If you want to emphasize some text, entering math mode as in `{$Threshold$}` is not the right way. Use `\emph` or `\textit` instead, e.g. `\textit{Threshold}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably forgotten one of two packages used in the preamble below. The rest of your document remains unchainged. If you really want to remowe the first column, please confirm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|l| c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline

    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Jaro-Winkler} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TF-IDF (3-gram)} \\ \hline
    % & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Soft TF-IDFT} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Soft TF-IDFT (3-gram)} \\ \hline

  Index  & {$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}      &{$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}
    & {$Threshold$} & {$Purity$} & {$Zrand$} & {$NMI$}  \\ \hline


   1 &0 &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0  &0.2789 &37.68  &0.7439     &0  &0.2395 &32.81  &0.7201 \\ \hline %Row 1

   2 &0.2   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.2    &0.9583 &463.18 &0.9003  &0.2   &0.8483 &271.59  &0.8872 \\ \hline %Row 2

   3 &0.4   &0.0023 &NaN    &0.4670     &0.4    &0.9907 &445.94 &0.9318  &0.4   &0.9861 &484.57  &0.9159 \\ \hline %Row 3

  4  &0.6   &0.0034 &0.5916 &0.4676  &0.6   &0.9976 &374.23 &0.9299 &0.6    &0.9942 &410.28 &0.9308 \\ \hline %Row 4

   5 &0.8   &0.1944 &16.18  &0.6317 &0.8    &0.9976 &283.43 &0.9285 &0.8    &0.9976 &326.86 &0.9291 \\ \hline %Row 5

   6 &1 &0.9629 &207.14 &0.9074     &1  &0.9976 &33.29  &0.9266     &1  &0.9976 &156.52 &0.9273 \\ \hline %Row 6

  A  &0.8942    &0.9548 &193.84 &0.9060 &0.5522 &0.9837 &470.70 &0.9156 &0.5943 &0.9814 &472.90  &0.9155 \\ \hline %Row 7

\end{tabular}}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `here` is an obsolete package. Run `texdoc here`.