# Ideas for a Presentation on Tabular Environment

Tags: tables, fun

As above, I will soon need to give a presentation on `tabular` environment. You might very well wonder why. Apparently the aim of such presentation is to gain 'presentation' skills.

Anyhow, my question is: Do you know any "fun thing" about the `tabular` environment? Something which could make a presentation alive?

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, use as much vertical lines as possible -- this will strike! And make @egreg faint ;-)

Comment: Use funny content? Ducks are first choice, wombats come next. But i don't think this is *on-topic* here?

Comment: To be honest: `tabular` is not really funny at all and perhaps one of the most boring topics -- or do have seen funny tables so far? ;-)

Comment: Making good looking tabulars can take quite some time and is not very funny. Also a lot of the tricks are rather technical. Depending on the audience you could show how to hide columns (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263953/table-on-a-double-page/263956#263956, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204409/hide-multicolumns/204418#204418),

Comment: you should explain why all tabular macros use `{\ifnum0=\`}\fi` to open a group and `\ifnum0=\`{\fi}` to close it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: No, that's too funny -- it would be like Monty Python's lethal joke by Ernest Scribbler ;-)

Comment: Even though this might be opinion-based, I think it admits valuable serious answers. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

As has been mentioned in comments, designing good tables is not an easy job and is, in general, not much fun. However, you can make a good entertaining and educational presentation by doing something similar to André Vatter's animation on how to improve tables, which can be found [`here`](http://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/).

[image]

In this way you will have the opportunity to

1. Practice/improve your skills on overlay specifications/animations in your presentation
2. Teach a valuable lesson about designing professional looking tables.