# Insert or edit single column into existing LaTeX table

Tags: tables

I would like to know if there's an easier way than editing each row separately.
This should be a quite common problem, when adding additional columns I often stumbled over this issue and always resorted to just editing each row by hand.

Is there any LaTeX editor which perhaps offers additional table editing capabilities?

Comment: You could try online editors that let you add columns. One example: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables (the file menu offers the option to import LaTeX code).

Comment: You can do this in Texstudio.

Comment: See also here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55995/101651 and here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262616/101651

Comment: I searched for an answer, but apparently didn't phrase it properly to come up with the other answers. Sorry, perhaps it's now easier to find.

Comment: I am now facing the same issue and quite frankly none of the answers on any of the other questions is really satisfactory. I would like to copy over a column of data from libre office calc and it's just not possible to just paste it into one of the table columns in TeXstudio.