# How to uncover a table column wise in Latex beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

I have a table with 7 columns and want to show the first 5 at once, and then  the 6th and 7th on consecutive slides.

This is the code I have for now:

```
\begin{frame}{Наслов}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Ставка.
    \end{itemize}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc<{\onslide<2->}c<{\onslide}c}
            $p_1$ & $p_2$ & $\ldots$ & $p_{9}$ & $p_{10}$ & $W$  & $D$\\
            $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $1$      & $1$     & $w_1$& $d_1$\\
            $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $1$      & $0$     & $w_2$& $d_2$\\
            $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $1$     & $w_3$& $d_3$\\
            $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $0$     & $w_4$& $d_4$\\
            $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\\
            $0$   & $0$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $1$     & $w_{1023}$& $d_{1023}$\\
            $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $0$     & $w_{1024}$& $d_{1024}$
        \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

This produces 2 slides: the first one with p1, p2, ..., p9, p10 and D columns, and the second with W added, while I want them to appear in the following order:

- 1st slide: p1, p2, ..., p9, p10
- 2nd slide: p1, p2, ..., p9, p10, W
- 3rd slide: p1, p2, ..., p9, p10, W, D

I looked in the manual and found this example:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule}c<{\onslide<2->}c<{\onslide<3->}c<{\onslide<4->}c<{\onslide}c}
    Class & A & B & C & D \\
    217
    X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

which does what is supposed to. However, I don't seem to be able to apply its logic to my problem. :( Is anyone willing to help?

P.S. What are the meanings of < and ! in columns specification?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following seems to do what you're asking for, after adding [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array) to the preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc<{\onslide<2->}c<{\onslide<3->}c<{\onslide}}
    $p_1$ & $p_2$ & $\ldots$ & $p_{9}$ & $p_{10}$ & $W$  & $D$\\
    $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $1$      & $1$     & $w_1$& $d_1$\\
    $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $1$      & $0$     & $w_2$& $d_2$\\
    $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $1$     & $w_3$& $d_3$\\
    $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $0$     & $w_4$& $d_4$\\
    $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\\
    $0$   & $0$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $1$     & $w_{1023}$& $d_{1023}$\\
    $1$   & $1$   & $\ldots$ & $0$      & $0$     & $w_{1024}$& $d_{1024}$
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that setting `\setbeamercovered{dynamic}` prevents this from working. Putting `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` inside the frame fixes the issue.

Comment: It worked here even without the `collcell` package. This doesn't work with `\hline`, does it?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio: You need at least the [`array` package](//ctan.org/pkg/array) which supports the `>{..}` and `<{..}` notation. [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell) loads `array`. You might be interested in [Easiest way to delete a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/5764)

Comment: I am trying to do this with the separation bars in between columns and it is giving me an error -- i.e., if I change the tabular definition to \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|<{\onslide<2->}c|<{\onslide<3->}c<{\onslide}|}. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @ozsu: See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/cHpFXaRt). You can only insert content immediately before or after the *column*, not the vertical rules. If you want to have an `\onslide` rule, then you have to insert it using `\vrule`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks very much; that works and I've learned something new. Is there a way to put \hline (or equivalent) to show the line progressively? I can put \hline, but it shows it across the entire set of columns from the beginning rather than revealing progressively.

Comment: @ozsu: One thing to consider here is that you're creating a presentation... and in a presentation you're trying to introduce a flow of the information, which might not follow the convention of the coding. So, in such a case, how about [this](https://pastebin.com/fnXT83t4)? It creates separate `tabular`s that are displayed next to one another. Without spaces between then (due to `%`), you can display them as needed and everything will line up (rule-wise). If not, you could introduce `\phantom`s to ensure this. [Here is such a paste](https://pastebin.com/DzzYrgic), just to show what I mean.

Comment: @Werner Thanks much; I will study both of these.