# Onslide command on column tables while keeping the heading fixed

Tags: tables, beamer, columns

I have the following table where I compare OLS and quantile regressions. I would like to use the `onslide` command to have the last three columns to appear in a second moment (hopefully keeping the heading fixed, so that only the coefficients show up in a second moment).

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{r @{} l}}
            \hline
            &  (I)  &        &  (II)&        &  (III)&        &  (IV)&         \\
            &    OLS    &        &    Q1&        &    Q2&        &    Q3&         \\
            \hline
A&        xxx&$^{**}$       &      xxx&$^{***}$             &        xxx&$^{**}$                &        xxx&$^{***}$\\
                &      (yyy)&        &     (yyy)&           &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        \\
B&        xxx&          &       xxx&$^{**}$             &        xxx&$^{***}$               &        xxx&$^{**}$\\
                &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This thread provides a close solution using the `<\onslide>` command [How to uncover a table column wise in Latex beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274920/how-to-uncover-a-table-column-wise-in-latex-beamer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). However, with this approach the headings would show up at the same time as the coefficients.

Also, I would like to keep the command `\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{r @{} l}}` and not `\begin{tabular}{l rl rl rl rl}` as the former provides a nicer output with the stars closer to the left border.

Comment: why you use document class `article` if you like to have solotion possible only in `beamer`?

Comment: Oh sorry! you're right I corrected it!

Comment: @Andrew: Your MWE still deos not contain a `frame`. Please also note, that using a floating environment like `table`  is not necessary if you don't want to add a caption. Generally, nesting a `tabular` insde a `center` environment is not advisable, as it adds additional vertical space. You can use `\centering` instead.

Comment: @Andrew Actually you can simply drop the `center` environment, as beamer centres tables by default (as long as the `table` environment is used, which is not a float in beamer)

Comment: I know, I just copied the table from an article, and I forgot to modify it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the following solution, that shows the first column, as well as the other column's headings and all horizontal lines on the first slide and adds the remaining data on a second slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1->}l >{\onslide<1->}r @{} >{\onslide<1->}l *3{>{\onslide<2->}r @{} >{\onslide<2->}l}}
            \hline
            &  (I)  &        & \onslide<1-> (II)&        & \onslide<1-> (III)&        &  \onslide<1->(IV)&         \\
            &    OLS    &        &   \onslide<1-> Q1&        &   \onslide<1-> Q2&        &   \onslide<1-> Q3&         \onslide<1->\\
           \hline
A&        xxx&$^{**}$       &      xxx&$^{***}$             &        xxx&$^{**}$                &        xxx&$^{***}$\\
                &      (yyy)&        &     (yyy)&           &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        \\
B&        xxx&          &       xxx&$^{**}$             &        xxx&$^{***}$               &        xxx&$^{**}$\\
                &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&        &      (yyy)&       \onslide<1-> \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]