# Beamer: show a column in the second slide of a tabu

Tags: beamer, tabu

I need to prepare a tabular where the third and the sixth rows appear only in the second slide, for their elements are the answer of the exercise. I attempted putting a general `\onslide<2->` in `>` but it doesn't work. Can someone fix that for me, please?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Activity}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth 
 {*{3}{>{\bfseries}X[0.2rm]X[lm$]>{\color{Blue}}X[lm$]}}
% Exercise
1) & 3x + 6 & 3(x+2) & 2) & 5x+15 & 5(x+3) & 3) & 4x+20 & 4(x+5) \cr
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `\visible` to the individual elements you want to uncover:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Activity}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth 
 {*{3}{>{\bfseries}X[0.2rm]X[lm$]>{\color{blue}}X[lm$]}}
% Exercise
1) & 3x + 6 & \visible<2->{3(x+2)} & 2) & 5x+15 & \visible<2->{5(x+3)} & 3) & 4x+20 & \visible<2->{4(x+5)} \cr
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Actually, I thought the same thing, but I discarded it as there are 20 rows in the original table, and the result is a nightmare. Isn't it a way to automatise it, somehow?

Comment: @Logos see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274922/36296

Comment: Aye, it works perfectly, though I have not understand the reason for the package `array` and why `<` is used instead of `>`.