# Remove specific column from multiple tables

Tags: tables

Is there a way to add code in the beginning of a document in latex to ignore the second column for multiple tables?

Comment: Welcome, tables (i.e. tabulars) are used where you might now expect them, for example when printing the author(s) on the titlepage.

Comment: Related: [Easiest way to delete a column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `array` package one can create a new column type which will void all the data for one column.  You will still have to go through all your tabulars and change the column definitions, but you can leave the data intact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newsavebox{\bitbucket}

\newcolumntype{V}{>{\hspace{-2\tabcolsep}\savebox{\bitbucket}\bgroup}{c}<{\egroup}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
test & column & data\\
first & second & third
\end{tabular}}

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tabular}{cVc}
test & column & data\\
first & second & third
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular bit bucket]

Comment: Actually, it seems I reinvented the wheel here.  Se e http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column/16607#16607