# Tabular: Couple dimensions of one tabular to another tabular

Tags: tables, width

`tabular` sets column widths to the widest element across all rows.

Is it possible to set two or more separate `tabular`s to consider each other's column widths and pick the largest of the them?

For example, if I break a `tabular` with additional paragraph text and want to continue the tabular as if it were a `longtable` crossing onto the next page (same column widths, possibly reiterating the headers), would this be possible?

Comment: Isn't it easier to used fixed lengths for tabulars then?

Comment: Would the cells in both tabular be one-line only?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Autosize for the win. I hate specifying widths; I'm looking for a robust solution.

Comment: @Bernard Do you mean single row tabulars or do you mean each row is always equal to `1em` without increases from equations, multirow, or anything else? Either way: no. I'm looking for a robust solution which can handle anything.

Comment: I just mean: will your cells have line breaks, whether automatic or not?

Comment: Would you accept a solution based on the `\halign` TeX primitive?  I mean, are you ready to accept a not-so-user-friendly syntax for specifying the alignment of columns?

Comment: It can be done, and oddly enough is is based on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277901/remove-specific-column-from-multiple-tables/277958?s=1|1.4417#277958.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create a bunch of special column types such that every time this column type appears in a tabular it will always have the same width.  This requires 2 runs of the document, where the widths computed in the first run are saved in the aux file.

Note: If you ever want to make the columns narrower, you will need to delete the aux file or at least comment out the \AtEndDocument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}% \box0 etc. used

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saveWidth}[1]% #1=column name (A,B,...)
{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\initWidth{#1}{\the\csname Width#1\endcsname}}}

\newcommand{\initWidth}[2]% #1=column name (A,B,...), #2=the width
{\@ifundefined{Width#1}{}{\global\csname Width#1\endcsname=#2\relax}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\WidthA}% one for each column type
\newlength{\WidthB}
\newlength{\WidthC}

\AtEndDocument{\saveWidth{A}\saveWidth{B}\saveWidth{C}}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\savebox{\tempbox}\bgroup}{l}<{\egroup%
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox>\WidthA \global\WidthA=\wd\tempbox\fi%
  \makebox[\WidthA][l]{\usebox\tempbox}}}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\savebox{\tempbox}\bgroup}{c}<{\egroup%
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox>\WidthB \global\WidthB=\wd\tempbox\fi%
  \makebox[\WidthB][c]{\usebox\tempbox}}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\savebox{\tempbox}\bgroup}{r}<{\egroup%
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox>\WidthC \global\WidthC=\wd\tempbox\fi%
  \makebox[\WidthC][r]{\usebox\tempbox}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ABC}
left & center & right\\
wide left & wide center  & wide right
\end{tabular}

\medskip
Some text here.
\medskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ABC}
left & center & right\\
\end{tabular}

\medskip
Some text here.
\medskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ABC}
very wide left & very wide center & very wide right\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

To make it easier to create new columns, I added `\newcolumnwidth{<name>}{l/c/r}` (which is itself rather ugly).

```
\newcommand{\newcolumnwidth}[2]% #1=new column type, #2=l/c/r
{\expandafter\newlength\csname Width#1\endcsname%
 \AtEndDocument{\saveWidth{#1}}%
 \newcolumntype{#1}{>{\savebox{\tempbox}\bgroup}{#2}<{\egroup%
  \ifdim\wd\tempbox>\csname Width#1\endcsname \global\csname Width#1\endcsname=\wd\tempbox\fi%
  \makebox[\csname Width#1\endcsname][#2]{\usebox\tempbox}}}}

\newcolumnwidth{A}{l}
\newcolumnwidth{B}{c}
\newcolumnwidth{C}{r}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would follow is similar to what is done inside the `tabbing` environment. You set a first row that defines the tab stops and then `\kill` that row so it doesn't show. Subsequent rows will use these tab stops without the first row being present.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
  left      & center      &      right \\
  wide left & wide center & wide right
\end{tabular}

\medskip

Some text here.

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
  \phantom{wide left} &
    \phantom{wide center} & 
    \phantom{wide right} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]% Similar to \kill
  left      & center      &      right
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The "`\kill` row" in the above example places the widest elements across both of your tables inside a `\phantom`, while the height of the row is removed using a newline of the form `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`.

If the content to be hidden is very tall, use `\hphantom`. If you're concerned about overprinting of vertical rules, don't use them (as suggested by the awesome [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)) or insert each column element in the "`\kill` row" using `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` *without* vertical rules.