# Problems compiling a longtable

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, excel2latex

I'm currently working with a table consisting of a rather large amount of data and I want to split it onto more than one page. For this I want to use a longtable.

I simply used Excel2LaTeX in order to get my data from an excel sheet into a table and then tried to replace the table and tabular environment to a longtable environment.

This is my code, when it was a normal table everything was working just fine:

```
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{longtable}{llllrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Umsätze in EUR}} \\
\cmidrule{5-7}    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Firma}} & \textbf{Ort} & 
\textbf{PLZ} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Straße}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\textbf{2013}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2014}} & \multicolumn{1}{c} 
{\textbf{2015}} \\
Donau Büroeinrichtungen & Linz  & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9 & 51560.00 & 56716.00 & 62387.60 \\
Bürocenter Tirol & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstraße 234 & 480536.00 & 528589.60 & 581448.56 \\
Carynthia Firmenausstattung & Klagenfurt & 9201  & Kaiser-Franz-Str. 1806 & 199120.00 & 219032.00 & 240935.20 \\
Möbelhaus am Donaukanal & Wien  & 1050  & Kanalstraße 45 & 257817.00 & 283598.70 & 311958.57 \\
Mozart Möbel & Salzburg & 5020  & Salieristraße 34 & 33797.00 & 37176.70 & 40894.37 \\
Mödlinger Möbelhaus & Wien  & 1210  & Beethovengässchen 65 & 61960.00 & 68156.00 & 74971.60 \\
Almuts alternatives Möbelhaus & Hintertux & 6293  & Stallmannplatz 1 & 90205.00 & 99225.50 & 109148.05 \\
Möbelhaus Borsche & Stuttgart & 70376 & Industriestraße 34 & 365711.00 & 402282.10 & 442510.31 \\
Breitlingcenter & Rostock & 18119 & Warnowstraße 110 & 42791.00 & 47070.10 & 51777.11 \\
Berliner Möbelhaus & Berlin & 10131 & Masha-Straße 41 & 278208.00 & 306028.80 & 336631.68 \\
Büroaustattung Balzer & Frankfurt/Main & 60435 & Carmenplatz 23 & 125951.00 & 138546.10 & 152400.71 \\
Schweriner Möbelhaus & Schwerin & 19123 & Kaiserstraße 34 & 144480.00 & 158928.00 & 174820.80 \\
Möbelfleet & Kiel  & 24123 & Graf-Luckner-Platz 16 & 83556.00 & 91911.60 & 101102.76 \\
Möbel Schulze & Bremen & 28121 & Kormoranstraße 34 & 67035.00 & 73738.50 & 81112.35 \\
Möbelhaus Deutsches Eck & Koblenz & 56068 & Wilhelmstraße 71 & 311029.00 & 342131.90 & 376345.09 \\
Badische Büromöbel GmbH & Freiburg/Br. & 79106 & Eschholzstr. 10 & 148496.00 & 163345.60 & 179680.16 \\
Luidolf-Einrichtungen GmbH & Quedlinburg & 06484 & Stiftsplatz 1 & 39400.00 & 43340.00 & 47674.00 \\
Goethe-Möbel & Weimar & 99123 & Auerbachstraße 36 & 147962.00 & 162758.20 & 179034.02 \\
Möbelzeche & Recklinghausen & 45665 & Immelmannstraße 1 & 484552.00 & 533007.20 & 586307.92 \\
Möbelhaus Spatz & Regensburg & 93123 & Domplatz 11 & 72533.00 & 79786.30 & 87764.93 \\
Jeetzedesign & Salzwedel & \multicolumn{1}{r}{29410} & Diesdorfer Straße 21 & 1492.00 & 1641.20 & 1805.32 \\
Bürocenter Rödelheim & Frankfurt/Main & 60123 & Waggonstraße 78 & 129718.00 & 142689.80 & 156958.78 \\
Otto GmbH & Havelberg & 39539 & Burghardstr. 4 & 132275.00 & 145502.50 & 160052.75 \\
Trifels Möbel & Annweiler & 76855 & Romanstraße 6 & 176361.00 & 193997.10 & 213396.81 \\
Möbelhaus Heinkel & Rostock & 18059 & Cannstatter Str. 12 & 374363.00 & 411799.30 & 452979.23 \\
Möbelhaus Bad Doberan & Bad Doberan & 18209 & Klosterstraße 12 & 70816.00 & 77897.60 & 85687.36 \\
Saarmöbel & Saarbrücken & 66111 & Nebenstraße 23 & 454900.00 & 500390.00 & 550429.00 \\
Ilmenauer \& Co. & Saarlouis & 66740 & Alter Weg 58 & 41926.00 & 46118.60 & 50730.46 \\
Möbel Engert & Frankfurt/Main & 60314 & Eckhardtstraße 89 & 192556.00 & 211811.60 & 232992.76 \\
Bürocenter St. Pirmin & Pirmasens & 66953 & Adelheidstr. 78 & 309360.00 & 340296.00 & 374325.60 \\
Möbelstube Degehardt & Köln  & 51069 & Hartplatz 44 & 93188.00 & 102506.80 & 112757.48 \\
Mannis Möbelscheune & Aachen & 52111 & Im Weg 13 & 98669.00 & 108535.90 & 119389.49 \\
Büromeister GmbH & Hamburg & 20122 & Wasserfahrt 4 & 382413.00 & 420654.30 & 462719.73 \\
Büro Mayer & Offenbach/Main & 63123 & Bieberer Straße 34 & 117371.00 & 129108.10 & 142018.91 \\
Möbel-Dreyer & Potsdam & 14482 & Windspielplatz 16 & 208725.00 & 229597.50 & 252557.25 \\
Donau-Inn-Ilz Möbelhaus & Passau & 94034 & Seidelhof 7 & 393262.00 & 432588.20 & 475847.02 \\
LifeStyleTemple & Berlin & 10011 & Kurfüstendamm 456 & 20063.00 & 22069.30 & 24276.23 \\
Möbelhaus Morath & Lübeck & 23123 & Grünlichplatz 3 & 144253.00 & 158678.30 & 174546.13 \\
Büroausstattung am Stachus & München & 90123 & Karlsplatz 23 & 52149.00 & 57363.90 & 63100.29 \\
Schreinerei Schröder & Hannover & 30123 & Maschseeaue 52 & 41434.00 & 45577.40 & 50135.14 \\
Alstermöbel & Hamburg & 20122 & Hartmannsaue 9 & 117536.00 & 129289.60 & 142218.56 \\
Kaiser-Friedrich-Möbel & Wiesbaden & 65189 & Thermenstraße 2 & 426058.00 & 468663.80 & 515530.18 \\
Schreinerei Radtke & Hoyerswerda & 02977 & Holzweg 42 & 413439.00 & 454782.90 & 500261.19 \\
Büroausstattung Ilmtal & Apolda & 99510 & Hauptstraße 67 & 144705.00 & 159175.50 & 175093.05 \\
Büroausstattung Murkel & Paderborn & 33123 & Konviktstraße 14 & 125877.00 & 138464.70 & 152311.17 \\

\pagebreak

Kultsofa KG & Mainz & 55116 & Augustinergasse 23 & 10207.00 & 11227.70 & 12350.47 \\
Möbel Döbel & Dillingen & \multicolumn{1}{r}{66763} & Saarstraße 42 & 61160.00 & 67276.00 & 74003.60 \\
Wachwitzmöbel & Dresden & 01326 & Corneliengasse 13 & 229912.00 & 252903.20 & 278193.52 \\
Jugendmöbel & Darmstadt & 64283 & Grafenstraße 59 & 174190.00 & 191609.00 & 210769.90 \\
Möbelwiese & Ludwigshafen & 67061 & Evastraße 23 & 361121.00 & 397233.10 & 436956.41 \\
Semper-Möbel & Dresden & 01326 & Seidemannstraße 72 & 134288.00 & 147716.80 & 162488.48 \\
Büromöbelzentrum & Magdeburg & 39123 & Königin-Edith-Straße 2 & 60324.00 & 66356.40 & 72992.04 \\
Bürohaus Hauser & Cottbus & 03123 & Anselmstraße 11 & 48790.00 & 53669.00 & 59035.90 \\
Büro-Discount & Erfurt & 99123 & Grünwiese 345 & 53480.00 & 58828.00 & 64710.80 \\
Weserbüro OHG & Bremen & 28113 & Rolandsweg 11 & 94678.00 & 104145.80 & 114560.38 \\
Büromöbel Karly & Zerbst & 39261 & Archivstraße 45 & 140715.00 & 154786.50 & 170265.15 \\
Bürocenter & Bremen & 28122 & Klarastraße 13 & 32288.00 & 35516.80 & 39068.48 \\
Möbelhaus Niederschlesien & Görlitz & 02123 & Berliner Straße 34 & 135089.00 & 148597.90 & 163457.69 \\
Möbelhaus Pfleiderer & Ulm   & 89123 & Schwabenplatz 15 & 129664.00 & 142630.40 & 156893.44 \\
Stolz KG & Potsdam & 14123 & Havelaue 37 & 144157.00 & 158572.70 & 174429.97 \\
Emscher-Bürocenter & Dortmund & 44139 & Rasenplatz 45 & 248087.00 & 272895.70 & 300185.27 \\
Frisia Büro & Aurich & 26124 & Dorotheenweg 78 & 66096.00 & 72705.60 & 79976.16 \\
Möbelcenter Wilhelmshöhe & Kassel & 34123 & Sedanstraße 51 & 150304.00 & 165334.40 & 181867.84 \\
Fugger Bürocenter & Augsburg & 86150 & Alte Gasse 34 & 4852.00 & 5337.20 & 5870.92 \\
Wannsee-Büro GmbH & Berlin & 10122 & Wackerstr. 19 & 283149.00 & 311463.90 & 342610.29 \\
Biomöbel Gera & Gera  & 07546 & Halbstraße 62 & 263447.00 & 289791.70 & 318770.87 \\
Neckar-Büro OHG & Tübingen & 72076 & Konviktstraße 55 & 150514.00 & 165565.40 & 182121.94 \\
KdO   & Berlin & 10123 & Marthastraße 34 & 109917.00 & 120908.70 & 132999.57 \\
Möbelhansa & Hamburg & 20123 & Helgoländer Allee 53 & 111880.00 & 123068.00 & 135374.80 \\
\caption{Add caption} \\
\label{tab:lt} \\
\end{longtable}}
\end{center}
```

Later on I'd also like to format it with \endhead and other commands, but currently have trouble understanding why it isn't compiling at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How crucial is it to show the (euro) cents? Quite a bit of space could be saved by rounding to the nearest whole euro...

Comment: Yes, it is required to look exactly like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you (a) provide a bit more formal structure to the headers and footers of the `longtable`, (b) use the rounding facilities of the `siunitx` package to suppress the euro-cent data [I really can't imagine that anything of any consequence could depend on the cent data], and (c) reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace. To let `longtable` determine page breaks, get rid of the `center` environment. And do place the caption at the top rather than at the bottom of the `longtable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % just a guess
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{2.65pt} % default: 6pt
\sisetup{table-format=6.0, group-digits=false,
         round-mode=places, round-precision=0}

\begin{longtable}{@{}llrlSSS@{}}
\caption{Add caption} \label{tab:lt} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Firma} & \textbf{Ort} & 
\textbf{PLZ}   & \textbf{Straße} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Umsätze in EUR}} \\
\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
&&&& {\textbf{2013}} & {\textbf{2014}} & {\textbf{2015}} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\tablename\ \ref{tab:lt}, fortgesetzt \\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\textbf{Firma} & \textbf{Ort} & 
\textbf{PLZ}   & \textbf{Straße} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Umsätze in EUR}} \\
\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
&&&& {\textbf{2013}} & {\textbf{2014}} & {\textbf{2015}} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (fortgesetzt auf der nächsten Seite)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Donau Büroeinrichtungen & Linz  & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9 & 51560.00 & 56716.00 & 62387.60 \\
Bürocenter Tirol & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstraße 234 & 480536.00 & 528589.60 & 581448.56 \\
Carynthia Firmenausstattung & Klagenfurt & 9201  & Kaiser-Franz-Str. 1806 & 199120.00 & 219032.00 & 240935.20 \\
Möbelhaus am Donaukanal & Wien  & 1050  & Kanalstraße 45 & 257817.00 & 283598.70 & 311958.57 \\
Mozart Möbel & Salzburg & 5020  & Salieristraße 34 & 33797.00 & 37176.70 & 40894.37 \\
Mödlinger Möbelhaus & Wien  & 1210  & Beethovengässchen 65 & 61960.00 & 68156.00 & 74971.60 \\
Almuts alternatives Möbelhaus & Hintertux & 6293  & Stallmannplatz 1 & 90205.00 & 99225.50 & 109148.05 \\
Möbelhaus Borsche & Stuttgart & 70376 & Industriestraße 34 & 365711.00 & 402282.10 & 442510.31 \\
Breitlingcenter & Rostock & 18119 & Warnowstraße 110 & 42791.00 & 47070.10 & 51777.11 \\
Berliner Möbelhaus & Berlin & 10131 & Masha-Straße 41 & 278208.00 & 306028.80 & 336631.68 \\
Büroaustattung Balzer & Frankfurt/Main & 60435 & Carmenplatz 23 & 125951.00 & 138546.10 & 152400.71 \\
Schweriner Möbelhaus & Schwerin & 19123 & Kaiserstraße 34 & 144480.00 & 158928.00 & 174820.80 \\
Möbelfleet & Kiel  & 24123 & Graf-Luckner-Platz 16 & 83556.00 & 91911.60 & 101102.76 \\
Möbel Schulze & Bremen & 28121 & Kormoranstraße 34 & 67035.00 & 73738.50 & 81112.35 \\
Möbelhaus Deutsches Eck & Koblenz & 56068 & Wilhelmstraße 71 & 311029.00 & 342131.90 & 376345.09 \\
Badische Büromöbel GmbH & Freiburg/Br. & 79106 & Eschholzstr. 10 & 148496.00 & 163345.60 & 179680.16 \\
Luidolf-Einrichtungen GmbH & Quedlinburg & 06484 & Stiftsplatz 1 & 39400.00 & 43340.00 & 47674.00 \\
Goethe-Möbel & Weimar & 99123 & Auerbachstraße 36 & 147962.00 & 162758.20 & 179034.02 \\
Möbelzeche & Recklinghausen & 45665 & Immelmannstraße 1 & 484552.00 & 533007.20 & 586307.92 \\
Möbelhaus Spatz & Regensburg & 93123 & Domplatz 11 & 72533.00 & 79786.30 & 87764.93 \\
Jeetzedesign & Salzwedel & 29410 & Diesdorfer Straße 21 & 1492.00 & 1641.20 & 1805.32 \\
Bürocenter Rödelheim & Frankfurt/Main & 60123 & Waggonstraße 78 & 129718.00 & 142689.80 & 156958.78 \\
Otto GmbH & Havelberg & 39539 & Burghardstr. 4 & 132275.00 & 145502.50 & 160052.75 \\
Trifels Möbel & Annweiler & 76855 & Romanstraße 6 & 176361.00 & 193997.10 & 213396.81 \\
Möbelhaus Heinkel & Rostock & 18059 & Cannstatter Str. 12 & 374363.00 & 411799.30 & 452979.23 \\
Möbelhaus Bad Doberan & Bad Doberan & 18209 & Klosterstraße 12 & 70816.00 & 77897.60 & 85687.36 \\
Saarmöbel & Saarbrücken & 66111 & Nebenstraße 23 & 454900.00 & 500390.00 & 550429.00 \\
Ilmenauer \& Co. & Saarlouis & 66740 & Alter Weg 58 & 41926.00 & 46118.60 & 50730.46 \\
Möbel Engert & Frankfurt/Main & 60314 & Eckhardtstraße 89 & 192556.00 & 211811.60 & 232992.76 \\
Bürocenter St. Pirmin & Pirmasens & 66953 & Adelheidstr. 78 & 309360.00 & 340296.00 & 374325.60 \\
Möbelstube Degehardt & Köln  & 51069 & Hartplatz 44 & 93188.00 & 102506.80 & 112757.48 \\
Mannis Möbelscheune & Aachen & 52111 & Im Weg 13 & 98669.00 & 108535.90 & 119389.49 \\
Büromeister GmbH & Hamburg & 20122 & Wasserfahrt 4 & 382413.00 & 420654.30 & 462719.73 \\
Büro Mayer & Offenbach/Main & 63123 & Bieberer Straße 34 & 117371.00 & 129108.10 & 142018.91 \\
Möbel-Dreyer & Potsdam & 14482 & Windspielplatz 16 & 208725.00 & 229597.50 & 252557.25 \\
Donau-Inn-Ilz Möbelhaus & Passau & 94034 & Seidelhof 7 & 393262.00 & 432588.20 & 475847.02 \\
LifeStyleTemple & Berlin & 10011 & Kurfüstendamm 456 & 20063.00 & 22069.30 & 24276.23 \\
Möbelhaus Morath & Lübeck & 23123 & Grünlichplatz 3 & 144253.00 & 158678.30 & 174546.13 \\
Büroausstattung am Stachus & München & 90123 & Karlsplatz 23 & 52149.00 & 57363.90 & 63100.29 \\
Schreinerei Schröder & Hannover & 30123 & Maschseeaue 52 & 41434.00 & 45577.40 & 50135.14 \\
Alstermöbel & Hamburg & 20122 & Hartmannsaue 9 & 117536.00 & 129289.60 & 142218.56 \\
Kaiser-Friedrich-Möbel & Wiesbaden & 65189 & Thermenstraße 2 & 426058.00 & 468663.80 & 515530.18 \\
Schreinerei Radtke & Hoyerswerda & 02977 & Holzweg 42 & 413439.00 & 454782.90 & 500261.19 \\
Büroausstattung Ilmtal & Apolda & 99510 & Hauptstraße 67 & 144705.00 & 159175.50 & 175093.05 \\
Büroausstattung Murkel & Paderborn & 33123 & Konviktstraße 14 & 125877.00 & 138464.70 & 152311.17 \\
Kultsofa KG & Mainz & 55116 & Augustinergasse 23 & 10207.00 & 11227.70 & 12350.47 \\
Möbel Döbel & Dillingen & 66763 & Saarstraße 42 & 61160.00 & 67276.00 & 74003.60 \\
Wachwitzmöbel & Dresden & 01326 & Corneliengasse 13 & 229912.00 & 252903.20 & 278193.52 \\
Jugendmöbel & Darmstadt & 64283 & Grafenstraße 59 & 174190.00 & 191609.00 & 210769.90 \\
Möbelwiese & Ludwigshafen & 67061 & Evastraße 23 & 361121.00 & 397233.10 & 436956.41 \\
Semper-Möbel & Dresden & 01326 & Seidemannstraße 72 & 134288.00 & 147716.80 & 162488.48 \\
Büromöbelzentrum & Magdeburg & 39123 & Königin-Edith-Straße 2 & 60324.00 & 66356.40 & 72992.04 \\
Bürohaus Hauser & Cottbus & 03123 & Anselmstraße 11 & 48790.00 & 53669.00 & 59035.90 \\
Büro-Discount & Erfurt & 99123 & Grünwiese 345 & 53480.00 & 58828.00 & 64710.80 \\
Weserbüro OHG & Bremen & 28113 & Rolandsweg 11 & 94678.00 & 104145.80 & 114560.38 \\
Büromöbel Karly & Zerbst & 39261 & Archivstraße 45 & 140715.00 & 154786.50 & 170265.15 \\
Bürocenter & Bremen & 28122 & Klarastraße 13 & 32288.00 & 35516.80 & 39068.48 \\
Möbelhaus Niederschlesien & Görlitz & 02123 & Berliner Straße 34 & 135089.00 & 148597.90 & 163457.69 \\
Möbelhaus Pfleiderer & Ulm   & 89123 & Schwabenplatz 15 & 129664.00 & 142630.40 & 156893.44 \\
Stolz KG & Potsdam & 14123 & Havelaue 37 & 144157.00 & 158572.70 & 174429.97 \\
Emscher-Bürocenter & Dortmund & 44139 & Rasenplatz 45 & 248087.00 & 272895.70 & 300185.27 \\
Frisia Büro & Aurich & 26124 & Dorotheenweg 78 & 66096.00 & 72705.60 & 79976.16 \\
Möbelcenter Wilhelmshöhe & Kassel & 34123 & Sedanstraße 51 & 150304.00 & 165334.40 & 181867.84 \\
Fugger Bürocenter & Augsburg & 86150 & Alte Gasse 34 & 4852.00 & 5337.20 & 5870.92 \\
Wannsee-Büro GmbH & Berlin & 10122 & Wackerstr. 19 & 283149.00 & 311463.90 & 342610.29 \\
Biomöbel Gera & Gera  & 07546 & Halbstraße 62 & 263447.00 & 289791.70 & 318770.87 \\
Neckar-Büro OHG & Tübingen & 72076 & Konviktstraße 55 & 150514.00 & 165565.40 & 182121.94 \\
KdO   & Berlin & 10123 & Marthastraße 34 & 109917.00 & 120908.70 & 132999.57 \\
Möbelhansa & Hamburg & 20123 & Helgoländer Allee 53 & 111880.00 & 123068.00 & 135374.80 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question about how to make the table fit within the available space. If the text block of your document isn't wide enough to display the `longtable` that's shown above, you should give serious consideration to simplifying the table by omitting columns with information that's likely of zero or infinitesimal consequence to the main objective of the table. I gather that the main purpose of the table is to display three years' worth of annual turnover data for a list of furniture stores. Surely, the street and maybe even the zip code columns are just about irrelevant; omitting them entirely might even help readers grasp the (more) relevant information you're trying to convey.

If you decide to go this route, do be aware that there is no need to delete the column(s) by hand. Instead, just set up a column type (called `H` below) that automatically hides its contents. See the posting [Easiest way to delete a column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16604/5001) for more information on the topic of automatically hiding columns in a tabular-like environment.

The following table implements this idea. It also tries to enliven the visual presentation by inserting a bit of whitespace after every 5th data row and by inserting a visual thousands-separator in the large numbers in the final three columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,siunitx}
% column type "H" to "Hide". See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16607/5001
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}l<{\egroup}@{}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\sisetup{locale=DE, table-format=6.0, 
         round-mode=places, round-precision=0, 
         group-minimum-digits=4}
\begin{longtable}{@{}llrHSSS@{}}
\caption{Add caption} \label{tab:lt} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Firma} & \textbf{Ort} & 
\textbf{PLZ}   & \textbf{Straße} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Umsätze in EUR}} \\
\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
&&&& {\textbf{2013}} & {\textbf{2014}} & {\textbf{2015}} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\tablename\ \ref{tab:lt}, fortgesetzt \\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\textbf{Firma} & \textbf{Ort} & 
\textbf{PLZ}   & \textbf{Straße} &
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Umsätze in EUR}} \\
\cmidrule(l){5-7}    
&&&& {\textbf{2013}} & {\textbf{2014}} & {\textbf{2015}} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (fortgesetzt auf der nächsten Seite)}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Donau Büroeinrichtungen & Linz  & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9 & 51560.00 & 56716.00 & 62387.60 \\
Bürocenter Tirol & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstraße 234 & 480536.00 & 528589.60 & 581448.56 \\
Carynthia Firmenausstattung & Klagenfurt & 9201  & Kaiser-Franz-Str. 1806 & 199120.00 & 219032.00 & 240935.20 \\
Möbelhaus am Donaukanal & Wien  & 1050  & Kanalstraße 45 & 257817.00 & 283598.70 & 311958.57 \\
Mozart Möbel & Salzburg & 5020  & Salieristraße 34 & 33797.00 & 37176.70 & 40894.37 \\ \addlinespace
Mödlinger Möbelhaus & Wien  & 1210  & Beethovengässchen 65 & 61960.00 & 68156.00 & 74971.60 \\
Almuts alternatives Möbelhaus & Hintertux & 6293  & Stallmannplatz 1 & 90205.00 & 99225.50 & 109148.05 \\
Möbelhaus Borsche & Stuttgart & 70376 & Industriestraße 34 & 365711.00 & 402282.10 & 442510.31 \\
Breitlingcenter & Rostock & 18119 & Warnowstraße 110 & 42791.00 & 47070.10 & 51777.11 \\
Berliner Möbelhaus & Berlin & 10131 & Masha-Straße 41 & 278208.00 & 306028.80 & 336631.68 \\ \addlinespace
Büroaustattung Balzer & Frankfurt/Main & 60435 & Carmenplatz 23 & 125951.00 & 138546.10 & 152400.71 \\
Schweriner Möbelhaus & Schwerin & 19123 & Kaiserstraße 34 & 144480.00 & 158928.00 & 174820.80 \\
Möbelfleet & Kiel  & 24123 & Graf-Luckner-Platz 16 & 83556.00 & 91911.60 & 101102.76 \\
Möbel Schulze & Bremen & 28121 & Kormoranstraße 34 & 67035.00 & 73738.50 & 81112.35 \\
Möbelhaus Deutsches Eck & Koblenz & 56068 & Wilhelmstraße 71 & 311029.00 & 342131.90 & 376345.09 \\  \addlinespace
Badische Büromöbel GmbH & Freiburg/Br. & 79106 & Eschholzstr. 10 & 148496.00 & 163345.60 & 179680.16 \\
Luidolf-Einrichtungen GmbH & Quedlinburg & 06484 & Stiftsplatz 1 & 39400.00 & 43340.00 & 47674.00 \\
Goethe-Möbel & Weimar & 99123 & Auerbachstraße 36 & 147962.00 & 162758.20 & 179034.02 \\
Möbelzeche & Recklinghausen & 45665 & Immelmannstraße 1 & 484552.00 & 533007.20 & 586307.92 \\
Möbelhaus Spatz & Regensburg & 93123 & Domplatz 11 & 72533.00 & 79786.30 & 87764.93 \\ \addlinespace
Jeetzedesign & Salzwedel & 29410 & Diesdorfer Straße 21 & 1492.00 & 1641.20 & 1805.32 \\
Bürocenter Rödelheim & Frankfurt/Main & 60123 & Waggonstraße 78 & 129718.00 & 142689.80 & 156958.78 \\
Otto GmbH & Havelberg & 39539 & Burghardstr. 4 & 132275.00 & 145502.50 & 160052.75 \\
Trifels Möbel & Annweiler & 76855 & Romanstraße 6 & 176361.00 & 193997.10 & 213396.81 \\
Möbelhaus Heinkel & Rostock & 18059 & Cannstatter Str. 12 & 374363.00 & 411799.30 & 452979.23 \\ \addlinespace
Möbelhaus Bad Doberan & Bad Doberan & 18209 & Klosterstraße 12 & 70816.00 & 77897.60 & 85687.36 \\
Saarmöbel & Saarbrücken & 66111 & Nebenstraße 23 & 454900.00 & 500390.00 & 550429.00 \\
Ilmenauer \& Co. & Saarlouis & 66740 & Alter Weg 58 & 41926.00 & 46118.60 & 50730.46 \\
Möbel Engert & Frankfurt/Main & 60314 & Eckhardtstraße 89 & 192556.00 & 211811.60 & 232992.76 \\
Bürocenter St. Pirmin & Pirmasens & 66953 & Adelheidstr. 78 & 309360.00 & 340296.00 & 374325.60 \\ \addlinespace
Möbelstube Degehardt & Köln  & 51069 & Hartplatz 44 & 93188.00 & 102506.80 & 112757.48 \\
Mannis Möbelscheune & Aachen & 52111 & Im Weg 13 & 98669.00 & 108535.90 & 119389.49 \\
Büromeister GmbH & Hamburg & 20122 & Wasserfahrt 4 & 382413.00 & 420654.30 & 462719.73 \\
Büro Mayer & Offenbach/Main & 63123 & Bieberer Straße 34 & 117371.00 & 129108.10 & 142018.91 \\
Möbel-Dreyer & Potsdam & 14482 & Windspielplatz 16 & 208725.00 & 229597.50 & 252557.25 \\ \addlinespace
Donau-Inn-Ilz Möbelhaus & Passau & 94034 & Seidelhof 7 & 393262.00 & 432588.20 & 475847.02 \\
LifeStyleTemple & Berlin & 10011 & Kurfüstendamm 456 & 20063.00 & 22069.30 & 24276.23 \\
Möbelhaus Morath & Lübeck & 23123 & Grünlichplatz 3 & 144253.00 & 158678.30 & 174546.13 \\
Büroausstattung am Stachus & München & 90123 & Karlsplatz 23 & 52149.00 & 57363.90 & 63100.29 \\
Schreinerei Schröder & Hannover & 30123 & Maschseeaue 52 & 41434.00 & 45577.40 & 50135.14 \\ \addlinespace
Alstermöbel & Hamburg & 20122 & Hartmannsaue 9 & 117536.00 & 129289.60 & 142218.56 \\
Kaiser-Friedrich-Möbel & Wiesbaden & 65189 & Thermenstraße 2 & 426058.00 & 468663.80 & 515530.18 \\
Schreinerei Radtke & Hoyerswerda & 02977 & Holzweg 42 & 413439.00 & 454782.90 & 500261.19 \\
Büroausstattung Ilmtal & Apolda & 99510 & Hauptstraße 67 & 144705.00 & 159175.50 & 175093.05 \\
Büroausstattung Murkel & Paderborn & 33123 & Konviktstraße 14 & 125877.00 & 138464.70 & 152311.17 \\ \addlinespace
Kultsofa KG & Mainz & 55116 & Augustinergasse 23 & 10207.00 & 11227.70 & 12350.47 \\
Möbel Döbel & Dillingen & 66763 & Saarstraße 42 & 61160.00 & 67276.00 & 74003.60 \\
Wachwitzmöbel & Dresden & 01326 & Corneliengasse 13 & 229912.00 & 252903.20 & 278193.52 \\
Jugendmöbel & Darmstadt & 64283 & Grafenstraße 59 & 174190.00 & 191609.00 & 210769.90 \\
Möbelwiese & Ludwigshafen & 67061 & Evastraße 23 & 361121.00 & 397233.10 & 436956.41 \\ \addlinespace
Semper-Möbel & Dresden & 01326 & Seidemannstraße 72 & 134288.00 & 147716.80 & 162488.48 \\
Büromöbelzentrum & Magdeburg & 39123 & Königin-Edith-Straße 2 & 60324.00 & 66356.40 & 72992.04 \\
Bürohaus Hauser & Cottbus & 03123 & Anselmstraße 11 & 48790.00 & 53669.00 & 59035.90 \\
Büro-Discount & Erfurt & 99123 & Grünwiese 345 & 53480.00 & 58828.00 & 64710.80 \\
Weserbüro OHG & Bremen & 28113 & Rolandsweg 11 & 94678.00 & 104145.80 & 114560.38 \\ \addlinespace
Büromöbel Karly & Zerbst & 39261 & Archivstraße 45 & 140715.00 & 154786.50 & 170265.15 \\
Bürocenter & Bremen & 28122 & Klarastraße 13 & 32288.00 & 35516.80 & 39068.48 \\
Möbelhaus Niederschlesien & Görlitz & 02123 & Berliner Straße 34 & 135089.00 & 148597.90 & 163457.69 \\
Möbelhaus Pfleiderer & Ulm   & 89123 & Schwabenplatz 15 & 129664.00 & 142630.40 & 156893.44 \\
Stolz KG & Potsdam & 14123 & Havelaue 37 & 144157.00 & 158572.70 & 174429.97 \\ \addlinespace
Emscher-Bürocenter & Dortmund & 44139 & Rasenplatz 45 & 248087.00 & 272895.70 & 300185.27 \\
Frisia Büro & Aurich & 26124 & Dorotheenweg 78 & 66096.00 & 72705.60 & 79976.16 \\
Möbelcenter Wilhelmshöhe & Kassel & 34123 & Sedanstraße 51 & 150304.00 & 165334.40 & 181867.84 \\
Fugger Bürocenter & Augsburg & 86150 & Alte Gasse 34 & 4852.00 & 5337.20 & 5870.92 \\
Wannsee-Büro GmbH & Berlin & 10122 & Wackerstr. 19 & 283149.00 & 311463.90 & 342610.29 \\ \addlinespace
Biomöbel Gera & Gera  & 07546 & Halbstraße 62 & 263447.00 & 289791.70 & 318770.87 \\
Neckar-Büro OHG & Tübingen & 72076 & Konviktstraße 55 & 150514.00 & 165565.40 & 182121.94 \\
KdO   & Berlin & 10123 & Marthastraße 34 & 109917.00 & 120908.70 & 132999.57 \\
Möbelhansa & Hamburg & 20123 & Helgoländer Allee 53 & 111880.00 & 123068.00 & 135374.80 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is lovely and exactly what I was looking for, thank you.
However the table is still too big for my textwidth, so I tried to use an `\adjustbox ` with it and this doesn't seem to work.
Got another tip on that?

Comment: @JustIlom: You should never use `adjustbox` for tables, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. You can set the font size to `footnotesize`, just before the `longtable` and put the whole in a group.

Comment: @JustIlom - Please tell us how how the textblock of your document is. (I had to make a semi-educated guess for my answer, as you didn't exactly provide much information about the dimensions of the textblock. Naturally, my guess could be -- and, in the end, was! -- incorrect.)

Comment: @JustIlom - If this were a table in my document, I'd omit the street column entirely. Do ask yourself: Is anyone in their right mind going to care one bit that, e.g., Donau Büroeinrichtungen in Linz is located at Schubertplatz 9 rather than at, say, Beethovenpark 21? I highly doubt it. As long as there's only furniture store per town, its street address must surely be utterly irrelevant for a table which is primarily meant to present turnover data for three years for each store. If you omit the street address column, your spacing issues will almost certainly be solved immediately.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I already figured it out with the help of another user. Also I do understand, that some information here might be unnecessary, however this isn't for personal use and was supposed to be styled exactly as given.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether `\pagebreak` is allowed in a longtable-environment: wouldn't it be easier to just make two separate tables, the second one starting where you put the `\pagebreak` command (this would also give you more control about where your pagebreak occurs)? Or, ideally, you would leave out the `\pagebreak` command altogether and let LaTeX decided where to put the pagebreak (longtable does this automatically).

Comment: I'm not sure either, but the \pagebreak doesn't change the outcome, the table can't be compiled even without it.

Also it is for a LaTeX course and unfortunately we are supposed to do it with a longtable.

Comment: Ah okay! Sorry, I hadn't checked that. It might be the added `\\`'s after the `\caption{}` and `\label{}` commands. If you could provide us with the packages you used, I could try to run the code myself and see what's wrong.

Comment: The `\\ ` are actually something I found in another post about longtables and helped to reduce the amount of errors.
`\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literatur-1718-gr4}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable} `
are some of the packages used. Unfortunately it is a quite lengthy main document and I simly use `include ` to stitch it all together.