# Remove column in \input{table.tex} without editing the table.tex file itself

Tags: input

I'm exporting a LaTeX table from Stata and adding it into a document using the input command. However, I don't want the document to display the last column in this table. The table file is going to be regenerated (overwritten) on a regular basis and so I don't want to edit it every single time. Is there a way to not show the column without editing the table file itself?

table.tex:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{cc}}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

main.tex:

```
\begin{document}
...
\input{table.tex}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `luaprogtable` package might be what you are looking for. Its fairly new and I have never used it, so I cannot give you specific solution. Docs say about modifying tables, maybe it will be helpfull.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I was thinking along the same lines but that requires that you can set the column type that is exported, this may not be possible.

Comment: Maybe you can write a preprocessing script in another language (Perl, Python, even `sed` or similar) and call that (with `\write18`) just before you call `\input`?

Comment: Is it that you **can't** modify table.tex, or you just don't want to change every line of the data?  I would keep the `\begin{table}` commands outside the file and leave only the contents.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column/16607#16607

Comment: @JohnKormylo The file gets overwritten whenever the Stata code is run, and this happens on a regular basis. Then I only have to recompile the main tex file to update the data. Stata exports the file with the ```\begin{table}``` commands so it would be annoying to delete that each time.

Comment: @Marijn thanks, but don't think I'd know how to do that.

Comment: @vader9280 which operating system do you use (Windows/Mac/Linux)? Do you have any programming language installed? I'm not sure but I think MikTeX (Windows) comes with a version of Perl because some helper programs use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can temporarily modify `tabular` to ignore the given argument and replace it with something else.

File temp.tex:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Table}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}
\input{temp.tex}

{% begin group
  \let\normaltabular=\tabular
  \let\endnormaltabular=\endtabular
  \renewenvironment{tabular}[1]{\normaltabular{cH}}{\endnormaltabular}%
  \input{temp.tex}
}% end group

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! Had to use ```\begin{tabular}{ccH@{\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}}``` to delete the last column though, explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column

Comment: Oops, didn't pay attention while copying.