# Can I hide a table column with the S type from siunitx?

Tags: tables, siunitx, columns

I found the related question [Easiest way to delete a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column), which has a good [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16607/174846) for regular c type columns. But my data is formatted in the S type from [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en), in the form of `value \pm error`. According to the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package, c is one of the supported column types, but the S type is not. Here is a MWE of what I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}} % hidden column for c
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}S<{\egroup}@{}} % hidden column for S

\begin{document}

\fbox{
  \begin{tabular}{ccSc} % current format of my table, I want to hide the S column
    one & two & \text{S-type column} & three\\
    1 & 2 & 2 \pm 1 & 3
  \end{tabular}
}

\fbox{
  \begin{tabular}{ccHc} % column hide solution from the linked question
    one & two & hide & three\\
    1 & 2 & H & 3
  \end{tabular}
}

\fbox{
  \begin{tabular}{ccc} % intended result
    one & two & three\\
    1 & 2 &  3
  \end{tabular}
}
    
\end{document}
```

The result is that in the second table, the third column is hidden. What I want to achieve is to hide the third column in the first table. But if I naively replace the S in the table format `{ccSc}` with my new G type `{ccGc}`, LaTeX throws an error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> \unskip \egroup 
                           \__siunitx_table_print: \relax \d@llarend \do@row...
l.14 }
      
?
```

Comment: Use H, what’s the problem?

Comment: @egreg the problem is that the entries in the table don't work with `c` or `H` because of the `2 \pm 1`. I get 

```! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.14 }```

Comment: Please, add a proper example, then.

Comment: @egreg What would a proper example look like? I thought I made a good MWE in my question. I could add the minimal non-working example, but it is only replacing S with G in the first table. Apologies if that is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add instructions to ignore `\pm`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\let\pm\relax}c<{\egroup}@{}} % hidden column for c

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format=1.0(1)]c}
one & two & \text{S-type column} & three\\
1 & 2 & 2 \pm 1 & 3
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccHc}
one & two & \text{S-type column} & three\\
1 & 2 & 2 \pm 1 & 3
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]