How to properly format a wide table in LaTeX and wrap text in the last column?
I'm working on a project where I need to present a large dataset in a table using LaTeX. However, I’m facing challenges with the width of the table, especially with the last column which contains very long text. I would like to either make the table wider, or ideally, move the long contents of the last column into the next row if it exceeds the width limit.
Here’s a small part of my dataset:
---- MAMMALIA ----

9606    Homo_sapiens    9445    ITM2B   integral_membrane_protein_2B    48233205    48270356    +   NC_000013.11    AAP88930.1|EAX08788.1|EAX08789.1|EAX08790.1|EAX08791.1|Q9Y287.1|AAP97148.1|AAD40370.1|AAG49434.1|AAD45280.1|AAF66130.1|BAA91210.1|AAH00554.1|AAH16148.1|AAP35509.1|ADO22246.1|NP_068839.1|NP_068839.1|NP_068839.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    5925    RB1 RB_transcriptional_corepressor_1    48303750    48481889    +   NC_000013.11    AAA53483.1|AAA53484.1|AAA65735.1|AAA65736.1|AAA65737.1|AAA65738.1|AAA65739.1|AAA65740.1|AAA65741.1|AAA65742.1|AAA65743.1|AAA65744.1|AAA65745.1|AAA65746.1|AAA65747.1|AAA65748.1|AAA65749.1|AAA65998.1|AAA82538.1|AAA82539.1|AAA82540.1|AAA82541.1|AAA82542.1|AAA82543.1|AAA82544.1|AAA82545.1|AAA82546.1|AAA82547.1|AAA82548.1|AAA82549.1|AAA82550.1|AAA82551.1|AAA82552.1|AAA82553.1|AAA82554.1|AAA82555.1|AAA82556.1|AAA82557.1|AAA82558.1|AAA82559.1|AAA82560.1|AAA82561.1|AAA82562.1|AAA82563.1|AAB59466.1|AAB59467.1|AAB59468.1|AAB59469.1|AAB59470.1|AAB59471.1|AAB59473.1|AAB59475.1|AAB59476.1|AAB59477.1|AAB59478.1|AAB59479.1|AAB59480.1|AAB59481.1|AAB59482.1|AAB59483.1|AAB59489.1|AAB59579.1|AAB59580.1|AAN41646.1|AAN64133.1|AAO62758.1|AAP39867.1|AAT66036.2|AAT77205.1|AAT77206.1|AAT77207.1|AAV84025.1|ABC47164.1|AXV44443.1|AXV44444.1|AXV44445.1|AXV44446.1|AXV44447.1|AXV44448.1|AXV44449.1|AXV44450.1|AXV44451.1|AXV44452.1|AXV44453.1|AXV44454.1|AXV44455.1|AXV44456.1|AXV44457.1|AXV44458.1|AXV44459.1|AXV44460.1|AXV44461.1|AXV44462.1|AXV44463.1|AXV44464.1|AXV44465.1|AXV44466.1|AXV44467.1|CAA34462.1|EAX08793.1|EAX08794.1|P06400.2|QPD00565.1|QPD00566.1|QPD00567.1|QPD00568.1|QPD00569.1|QPD00570.1|QPD00571.1|QPD00572.1|QPD00573.1|QPD00574.1|BAD92025.1|AAC26845.1|BAF83947.1|BAG61225.1|BAG62042.1|AAH39060.1|AAH40540.1|AAB59465.1|AAA69807.1|AAA60259.1|AAA69808.1|AAA69806.1|NP_000312.2|NP_000312.2|NP_000312.2|NP_001394094.1|NP_001394094.1|NP_001394095.1|NP_001394095.1|NP_001394096.1|NP_001394096.1|NP_001394097.1|NP_001394097.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    10161   LPAR6   lysophosphatidic_acid_receptor_6    48389570    48444668    -   NC_000013.11    AAL40065.1|AAN64134.1|EAX08796.1|EAX08797.1|P43657.3|AAB62190.1|BAG53764.1|BAG53867.1|BAD97109.1|AAH40850.1|AAH45651.1|AAH70295.1|AAI06757.1|CAD97634.1|CAD97680.1|CAD97687.1|ADZ31975.1|AEP43757.1|XP_047285975.1|XP_047285976.1|XP_047285977.1|XP_047285978.1|XP_047285979.1|XP_047285980.1|XP_054229962.1|XP_054229963.1|NP_001155969.1|NP_001155969.1|NP_001155969.1|NP_001155970.1|NP_001155970.1|NP_001155970.1|NP_001155970.1|NP_001364245.1|NP_001364245.1|NP_001364245.1|NP_001364246.1|NP_001364246.1|NP_001364246.1|NP_005758.2|NP_005758.2|NP_005758.2
9606    Homo_sapiens    1102    RCBTB2  RCC1_and_BTB_domain_containing_protein_2    48488962    48535894    -   NC_000013.11    AAP88928.1|CBX47529.1|EAX08799.1|EAX08800.1|O95199.1|BAD92780.1|AAC79987.1|BAG51149.1|BAG53723.1|BAG60659.1|BAG63022.1|BAG65384.1|BAG38065.1|AAH29052.1|XP_011533196.1|XP_047286023.1|XP_047286024.1|XP_047286025.1|XP_054230030.1|XP_054230031.1|XP_054230032.1|XP_054230033.1|NP_001259.1|NP_001259.1|NP_001273759.1|NP_001273759.1|NP_001273760.1|NP_001273760.1|NP_001273761.1|NP_001273761.1|NP_001339353.1|NP_001339353.1|NP_001339354.1|NP_001339354.1|NP_001339355.1|NP_001339355.1|NP_001339356.1|NP_001339356.1|NP_001339357.1|NP_001339357.1|NP_001339358.1|NP_001339358.1|NP_001339359.1|NP_001339359.1|NP_001339360.1|NP_001339360.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    124903173   LOC124903173    uncharacterized_LOC124903173    48504383    48506805    -   NC_000013.11    XP_047286780.1|XP_047302191.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    57105   CYSLTR2 cysteinyl_leukotriene_receptor_2    48653928    48711225    +   NC_000013.11    AAG17281.1|AAK69485.1|AAQ91330.1|BAB16379.1|BAB89316.1|CAC69300.1|CAC69324.1|CAD19004.1|CAD20523.1|CAD35281.1|CAD68128.1|CAJ58194.1|EAX08802.1|Q9NS75.1|BAB03601.1|BAD83598.1|BAF84428.1|AAW47925.1|AAH69160.1|AAH96832.1|ABO61874.1|ABO61875.1|ABO61876.1|ABO61877.1|ABO61878.1|ABO61879.1|ABO61880.1|ABO61881.1|NP_001295394.1|NP_001295394.1|NP_001295396.1|NP_001295396.1|NP_001295397.1|NP_001295397.1|NP_001295398.1|NP_001295398.1|NP_001295399.1|NP_001295399.1|NP_001295400.1|NP_001295400.1|NP_001295405.1|NP_001295405.1|NP_001295405.1|NP_001373941.1|NP_001373941.1|NP_001373942.1|NP_001373942.1|NP_001373943.1|NP_001373943.1|NP_065110.1|NP_065110.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    22862   FNDC3A  fibronectin_type_III_domain_containing_3A   48975290    49209778    +   NC_000013.11    EAX08803.1|EAX08804.1|EAX08805.1|EAX08806.1|EAX08807.1|EAX08808.1|EAX08809.1|EAX08810.1|Q9Y2H6.4|BAA76814.3|CAG44602.1|CAG44603.1|BAD18784.1|BAG63723.1|AAH60816.1|AAH70072.1|AAI32813.1|AAI36618.1|AAI44302.1|CAE45852.1|CAI45989.1|XP_011533299.1|XP_016875929.1|XP_016875932.1|XP_054230218.1|XP_054230219.1|XP_054230220.1|NP_001073141.1|NP_001073141.1|NP_001265367.1|NP_001265367.1|NP_055738.3|NP_055738.3
9606    Homo_sapiens    2862    MLNR    motilin_receptor    49220337    49222376    +   NC_000013.11    AAC26081.1|EAX08813.1|O43193.1|AAT35806.1|NP_001498.1|NP_001498.1|NP_001498.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    81602   CDADC1  cytidine_and_dCMP_deaminase_domain_containing_1 49247924    49293484    +   NC_000013.11    EAX08815.1|EAX08816.1|EAX08817.1|EAX08818.1|EAX08819.1|Q9BWV3.1|BAG59840.1|BAG35689.1|CAB70808.1|AAK16745.1|AAH09562.1|AAH32889.1|AAH48092.1|AAH70238.1|AAH92434.1|AAI25203.1|XP_006719934.1|XP_011533552.1|XP_011533553.1|XP_047286645.1|XP_047286646.1|XP_047286648.1|XP_054231027.1|XP_054231028.1|XP_054231029.1|XP_054231030.1|XP_054231031.1|XP_054231032.1|NP_001180407.1|NP_001180407.1|NP_112173.1|NP_112173.1
9606    Homo_sapiens    81617   CAB39L  calcium_binding_protein_39_like 49308649    49444063    -   NC_000013.11    CAC37735.1|EAX08820.1|EAX08821.1|EAX08822.1|EAX08823.1|Q9H9S4.3|BAB14147.1|AAO65176.1|AAQ93064.2|AAH10993.2|XP_047286649.1|XP_047286650.1|XP_047286651.1|XP_047286652.1|XP_047286653.1|XP_047286654.1|XP_047286655.1|XP_054231033.1|XP_054231034.1|XP_054231035.1|XP_054231036.1|NP_001073138.1|NP_001073138.1|NP_001274266.1|NP_001274266.1|NP_001274267.1|NP_001274267.1|NP_001274268.1|NP_001274268.1|NP_112187.2|NP_112187.2
9606    Homo_sapiens    107303344   SETDB2-PHF11    SETDB2-PHF11_readthrough    49444273    49528975    +   NC_000013.11    AFD33305.1|AFD33306.1|AFD33307.1|NP_001307656.1|NP_001307656.1

10090   Mus_musculus    14586   Gfra2   glial_cell_line_derived_neurotrophic_factor_family_receptor_alpha_2 71127546    71217279    +   NC_000080.7 AAK97483.1|EDL35875.1|EDL35876.1|O08842.2|AAC53548.1|AAC82464.1|AAC82465.1|BAE23689.1|BAE28825.1|AAI38562.1|NP_001289023.1|NP_001289024.1|NP_032141.2
10090   Mus_musculus    675947  Gm9195  predicted_gene_9195 72669099    72699093    -   NC_000080.7 XP_017171829.1
10090   Mus_musculus    102632425   Gm30500 predicted_gene,_30500   72709531    72729287    -   NC_000080.7 XP_017171830.1
10090   Mus_musculus    319448  Fndc3a  fibronectin_type_III_domain_containing_3A   72775387    72948140    -   NC_000080.7 EDL35868.1|EDL35869.1|Q8BX90.3|BAC28002.2|BAC33381.1|BAC98060.1|BAE43015.1|AAH22140.1|AAH47066.1|ABA82149.1|XP_006519178.2|XP_006519179.1|XP_006519181.1|XP_017171544.1|XP_030103717.1|XP_030103718.1|XP_036014558.1|XP_036014559.1|NP_997519.2
10090   Mus_musculus    100043721   Gm4606  predicted_gene_4606 73078158    73100932    -   NC_000080.7 XP_030104079.1
10090   Mus_musculus    70086   Cysltr2 cysteinyl_leukotriene_receptor_2    73263042    73286553    -   NC_000080.7 BAB86881.1|EDL35864.1|EDL35865.1|Q920A1.2|AAK97354.1|AAI32415.1|AAI32419.1|XP_030103861.1|NP_001155884.1|NP_598481.2
10090   Mus_musculus    105670  Rcbtb2  regulator_of_chromosome_condensation_(RCC1)_and_BTB_(POZ)_domain_containing_protein_2   73376184    73421494    +   NC_000080.7 EDL35861.1|EDL35862.1|EDL35863.1|Q99LJ7.1|BAC27316.1|BAC27319.1|BAE36068.1|AAH03224.1|AEK06433.1|AEK06434.1|XP_006518445.1|XP_006518446.1|XP_006518447.1|XP_006518448.1|XP_006518449.1|XP_006518451.1|XP_011243193.1|XP_011243194.1|XP_030103451.1|XP_030103452.1|XP_030103453.1|XP_030103454.1|XP_030103455.1|XP_036014266.1|XP_036014267.1|XP_036014268.1|XP_036014269.1|XP_036014270.1|NP_001164165.1|NP_598844.3
10090   Mus_musculus    19645   Rb1 RB_transcriptional_corepressor_1    73430297    73563445    -   NC_000080.7 EDL35859.1|P13405.2|BAB27493.3|BAE21400.1|BAE24548.1|BAE27194.1|BAE28533.1|AAH96525.1|ABD72475.1|AAA39964.1|XP_036014420.1|NP_033055.2
10090   Mus_musculus    67168   Lpar6   lysophosphatidic_acid_receptor_6    73475330    73477797    +   NC_000080.7 EDL35860.1|Q8BMC0.1|BAC28077.1|BAE41252.1|AAH47931.1|AAH69991.1|AAI45941.1|AAI45943.1|NP_780325.1
10090   Mus_musculus    16432   Itm2b   integral_membrane_protein_2B    73599665    73622728    -   NC_000080.7 EDL35857.1|EDL35858.1|O89051.1|BAA92766.1|BAA92767.1|BAB22220.1|BAB22365.1|BAB22653.1|BAB22877.1|BAB23828.1|BAB25935.1|BAC36212.1|BAC36822.1|BAE29510.1|BAE29523.1|BAE30633.1|BAE30773.1|BAE30922.1|BAE31278.1|BAE31387.1|BAE31452.1|BAE31632.1|BAE31723.1|BAE35002.1|BAE35073.1|BAE35235.1|BAE35242.1|BAE35374.1|BAE35517.1|BAE35628.1|BAE35970.1|AAH04731.1|AAH10320.1|AAH21786.1|AAC63851.1|NP_032436.1
10090   Mus_musculus    67381   Med4    mediator_complex_subunit_4  73747488    73755984    +   NC_000080.7 EDL35855.1|EDL35856.1|Q9CQA5.1|BAB26809.1|BAB27118.1|BAC37206.1|BAE26554.1|AAH24950.1|NP_080395.1

9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  608252  MLNR    motilin_receptor    2542186 2544341 -   NC_006604.4 BAG32139.1|NP_001121536.1|NP_001121536.1|NP_001121536.1|NP_001121536.1|NP_001121536.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  102153036   LOC102153036    basic_proline-rich_protein-like 2544340 2547875 +   NC_006604.4 XP_038312762.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  476914  FNDC3A  fibronectin_type_III_domain_containing_3A   2553052 2728962 -   NC_006604.4 XP_005633930.1|XP_005633932.1|XP_038286821.1|XP_038286822.1|XP_038286823.1|XP_038286824.1|XP_038286825.1|XP_038312509.1|XP_038312511.1|XP_038362209.1|XP_038362210.1|XP_038362211.1|XP_038362212.1|XP_038362213.1|XP_038425402.1|XP_038425403.1|XP_038425404.1|XP_038425405.1|XP_038425406.1|XP_038489570.1|XP_038489571.1|XP_038489572.1|XP_038489573.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  119865168   LOC119865168    formin-like_protein_14  2751038 2752673 +   NC_006604.4 XP_038312512.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  111091799   LOC111091799    uncharacterized_LOC111091799    2827149 2843047 +   NC_006604.4 XP_022263975.1|XP_022263976.2|XP_022263978.2|XP_022263979.1|XP_022263980.1|XP_022263981.1|XP_022263982.1|XP_022263983.1|XP_038286826.1|XP_038286827.1|XP_038286828.1|XP_038286829.1|XP_038286830.1|XP_038286831.1|XP_038286832.1|XP_038286833.1|XP_038362214.1|XP_038362215.1|XP_038362216.1|XP_038362217.1|XP_038362218.1|XP_038362219.1|XP_038362220.1|XP_038362221.1|XP_038425408.1|XP_038425409.1|XP_038425410.1|XP_038425411.1|XP_038425412.1|XP_038425413.1|XP_038425414.1|XP_038425415.1|XP_038489574.1|XP_038489575.1|XP_038489576.1|XP_038489577.1|XP_038489578.1|XP_038489579.1|XP_038489580.1|XP_038489581.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  485445  CYSLTR2 cysteinyl_leukotriene_receptor_2    2942923 2990493 -   NC_006604.4 XP_005633933.2|XP_005633934.2|XP_013961906.2|XP_022263985.2|XP_022263986.2|XP_022263987.2|XP_038286835.1|XP_038286836.1|XP_038286837.1|XP_038286838.1|XP_038286839.1|XP_038286840.1|XP_038362223.1|XP_038362224.1|XP_038362225.1|XP_038362226.1|XP_038362227.1|XP_038362228.1|XP_038425418.1|XP_038425419.1|XP_038425420.1|XP_038425421.1|XP_038425422.1|XP_038425423.1|XP_038489583.1|XP_038489584.1|XP_038489586.1|XP_038489587.1|XP_038489588.1|XP_038489589.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  485446  RCBTB2  RCC1_and_BTB_domain_containing_protein_2    3045831 3085507 +   NC_006604.4 XP_038286841.1|XP_038286842.1|XP_038286843.1|XP_038286844.1|XP_038286846.1|XP_038286847.1|XP_038286848.1|XP_038286849.1|XP_038286850.1|XP_038286851.1|XP_038286852.1|XP_038286853.1|XP_038286854.1|XP_038286855.1|XP_038286857.1|XP_038312827.1|XP_038312828.1|XP_038312829.1|XP_038312830.1|XP_038312831.1|XP_038312832.1|XP_038312833.1|XP_038312834.1|XP_038312835.1|XP_038312836.1|XP_038312837.1|XP_038362230.1|XP_038362231.1|XP_038362232.1|XP_038362233.1|XP_038362234.1|XP_038362235.1|XP_038362236.1|XP_038362237.1|XP_038362238.1|XP_038362239.1|XP_038362240.1|XP_038362241.1|XP_038362242.1|XP_038362243.1|XP_038362244.1|XP_038425425.1|XP_038425426.1|XP_038425428.1|XP_038425429.1|XP_038425430.1|XP_038425431.1|XP_038425432.1|XP_038425434.1|XP_038425435.1|XP_038425436.1|XP_038425437.1|XP_038425438.1|XP_038425440.1|XP_038425441.1|XP_038425442.1|XP_038489590.1|XP_038489592.1|XP_038489593.1|XP_038489594.1|XP_038489595.1|XP_038489596.1|XP_038489597.1|XP_038489598.1|XP_038489599.1|XP_038489600.1|XP_038489601.1|XP_038489602.1|XP_038489603.1|XP_038489604.1|XP_038489605.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  476915  RB1 RB_transcriptional_corepressor_1    3090616 3235457 -   NC_006604.4 AAD38807.1|AAF67147.1|XP_038286858.1|XP_038312838.1|XP_038362229.1|XP_038425424.1|XP_038490272.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  100856069   LPAR6   lysophosphatidic_acid_receptor_6    3139670 3141657 +   NC_006604.4 XP_022263997.1|XP_038286743.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  476916  ITM2B   integral_membrane_protein_2B    3283457 3311397 -   NC_006604.4 XP_038286861.1|XP_038312839.1|XP_038362246.1|XP_038425444.1|XP_038489608.1
9615    Canis_lupus_familiaris  476917  MED4    mediator_complex_subunit_4  3382962 3439509 +   NC_006604.4 XP_005642527.2|XP_038286863.1|XP_038286864.1|XP_038286865.1|XP_038286866.1|XP_038286867.1|XP_038286868.1|XP_038312552.1|XP_038312553.1|XP_038312554.1|XP_038312555.1|XP_038312556.1|XP_038362247.1|XP_038362248.1|XP_038362249.1|XP_038362250.1|XP_038362251.1|XP_038425445.1|XP_038425447.1|XP_038425448.1|XP_038425449.1|XP_038425450.1|XP_038489609.1|XP_038489610.1|XP_038489611.1|XP_038489612.1|XP_038489613.1|XP_038489614.1

13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100028666   LOC100028666    amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis_2_chromosomal_region_candidate_gene_11_protein-like   318867500   318870001   +   NC_008804.1 XP_016277417.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100022404   CAB39L  calcium_binding_protein_39_like 318952851   319119812   +   NC_008804.1 XP_001368695.1|XP_007495472.1|XP_007495473.1|XP_007495474.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100028776   CDADC1  cytidine_and_dCMP_deaminase_domain_containing_1 319140335   319199850   -   NC_008804.1 XP_001378718.1|XP_007495477.1|XP_007495478.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100028809   MLNR    motilin_receptor    319227872   319231124   -   NC_008804.1 XP_001378741.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100022484   FNDC3A  fibronectin_type_III_domain_containing_3A   319242876   319439341   -   NC_008804.1 XP_007495479.1|XP_007495480.1|XP_007495481.1|XP_007495482.1|XP_007495483.1|XP_016277418.1|XP_016277419.1|XP_016277420.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100028891   CYSLTR2 cysteinyl_leukotriene_receptor_2    319760316   319801860   -   NC_008804.1 XP_007495484.1|XP_007495485.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100619605   RCBTB2  RCC1_and_BTB_domain_containing_protein_2    319976100   320041060   +   NC_008804.1 XP_016288714.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100022630   RB1 RB_transcriptional_corepressor_1    320049753   320208888   -   NC_008804.1 XP_001368799.1|XP_016277421.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   103102093   LPAR6   lysophosphatidic_acid_receptor_6    320115897   320117958   +   NC_008804.1 XP_007495486.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100022655   ITM2B   integral_membrane_protein_2B    320265018   320300290   -   NC_008804.1 XP_001368833.1|XP_007495487.1
13616   Monodelphis_domestica   100022682   MED4    mediator_complex_subunit_4  320463445   320494786   +   NC_008804.1 XP_007495489.1|XP_007495490.1|XP_007495491.1

Below is the code I have attempted, along with the data I'm using. My LaTeX Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % To enable landscape pages
\usepackage{adjustbox} % To adjust table width
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better table lines
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables spanning multiple pages
\usepackage{geometry} % To control page margins

\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in} % Set smaller margins

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape} % Start of landscape page

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % Set left margin for longtable
\setlength\LTright{0pt} % Set right margin for longtable

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
\textbf{TaxID} & \textbf{Species} & \textbf{GeneID} & \textbf{Gene Symbol} & \textbf{Gene Name} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Strand} & \textbf{Chr} & \textbf{Accession} \\
\hline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 9445 & ITM2B & integral\_membrane\_protein\_2B & 48233205 & 48270356 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88930.1, EAX08788.1, EAX08789.1, EAX08790.1, EAX08791.1, Q9Y287.1, AAP97148.1, AAD40370.1, AAG49434.1, AAD45280.1, AAF66130.1, BAA91210.1, AAH00554.1, AAH16148.1, AAP35509.1, ADO22246.1, NP\_068839.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 5925 & RB1 & RB\_transcriptional\_corepressor\_1 & 48303750 & 48481889 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAA53483.1, AAA53484.1, AAA65735.1, AAA65736.1, AAA65737.1, AAA65738.1, AAA65739.1, AAA65740.1, AAA65741.1, AAA65742.1, AAA65743.1, AAA65744.1, AAA65745.1, AAB59466.1, AAB59467.1, AAB59468.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 10161 & LPAR6 & lysophosphatidic\_acid\_receptor\_6 & 48389570 & 48444668 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAL40065.1, AAN64134.1, EAX08796.1, P43657.3, BAD97109.1, BAG53764.1, XP\_047285975.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 1102 & RCBTB2 & RCC1\_and\_BTB\_domain\_containing\_protein\_2 & 48488962 & 48535894 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88928.1, CBX47529.1, O95199.1, BAD92780.1, BAG51149.1, BAG60659.1, NP\_001259.1, XP\_047286023.1, XP\_054230030.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 124903173 & LOC124903173 & uncharacterized\_LOC124903173 & 48504383 & 48506805 & - & NC\_000013.11 & XP\_047286780.1, XP\_047302191.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 57105 & CYSLTR2 & cysteinyl\_leukotriene\_receptor\_2 & 48653928 & 48711225 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAG17281.1, AAK69485.1, BAB16379.1, CAC69300.1, NP\_001295400.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 22862 & FNDC3A & fibronectin\_type\_III\_domain\_containing\_3A & 48975290 & 49209778 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9Y2H6.4, BAA76814.3, CAG44603.1, NP\_055738.3 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 2862 & MLNR & motilin\_receptor & 49220337 & 49222376 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAC26081.1, O43193.1, NP\_001498.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81602 & CDADC1 & cytidine\_and\_dCMP\_deaminase\_domain\_containing\_1 & 49247924 & 49293484 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9BWV3.1, XP\_054231027.1, XP\_054231032.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81617 & CAB39L & calcium\_binding\_protein\_39\_like & 49308649 & 49444063 & - & NC\_000013.11 & CAC37735.1, XP\_054231033.1, NP\_112187.2 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 107303344 & SETDB2-PHF11 & SETDB2-PHF11\_readthrough & 49444273 & 49528975 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AFD33305.1, NP\_001307656.1 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape} % End of landscape page

\end{document}

Problem Description:

The table does not expand to fill the full width of the landscape page, even though I am using pdflscape and longtable.
Long entries in the last column are overflowing instead of wrapping to the next line.

Questions:

How can I ensure the longtable expands to use the full width of the landscape page?
Is there a way to automatically wrap long entries in the last column so they do not overflow?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

(I've edited my answer to move the material I stated initially in an addendum into the main body of the answer code.)
Some suggestions:

The information in columns 1, 2, and 9 is identical across all rows for the groups humans, mice, dogs, and opossums. I have two suggestions on how to eliminate the redundancies: (a) Hide columns 1, 2, and 9 programmatically by using the H column type instead of, say, the c column type. The H column type may be defined as follows (code based on a posting provided on TeX.SE way back in 2011):
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}} 

And, (b) provide header rows such as
\multicolumn{10}{|l|}{Tax ID 9606, Species Homo sapiens, Chromosome NC\_000013.11} \\ 
\hline

to head up the groups of rows related to humans, mice, dogs, and opossums.

You need to allow automatic line breaking not only in column 10 but also in column 5. For the material in column 5, I suggest you change all instances of \_ to \_\allowbreak programmatically, to allow line breaks after the underscore symbols. See the code below for how this may be done.

Instead of employing a longtable environment, do use an xltabular environment. xltabular combines the capabilities of longtable and tabularx. Be sure to set the table's target width to \linewidth and use the X column type for columns 5 and 10. See the code below for how to make the usable width of column 10 fifty percent larger than that of column 5.

Optional: Use automatic math mode in column 8, so that the - characters may be typeset as beefy math-minus symbols instead of as puny-looking text-dash symbols.



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    % For landscape-mode pages
%%%\usepackage{adjustbox} % Please never 'adjustbox' to format tables
%%%\usepackage{booktabs}  % You don't seem to be using this package
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=1in} % Set margins and paper size

%%% new code
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for a more-visible underscore symbol
\usepackage{xltabular} % for tables spanning multiple pages with a predetermined target width
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{array}     % for '\newcolumntype' macro

%%% Define four [4] new column types
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % centered, automatic math mode. Fol col. 8.
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}} % cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16607/5001  
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\renewcommand{\_}{\textunderscore\allowbreak}}L{#1}} % redefine "\_"

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape} % Start of landscape mode

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % Set left margin for longtable
\setlength\LTright{0pt} % Set right margin for longtable
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % for a less-cramped look
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default is 6pt

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| H H l | l | M{0.8} | l | l | C | H L{1.2} |}
   % Note: 0.8+1.2 = 2 = total number of X-type columns in the table


%%% headers and footers

\hline
\textbf{TaxID} & \textbf{Species} & \textbf{Gene ID} & 
\textbf{Gene Symbol} & \textbf{Gene Name} & \textbf{Start} & 
\textbf{End} & \textbf{Strand} & \textbf{Chr} & \textbf{Accession} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{10}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot


%%% body of table

\multicolumn{10}{|l|}{Tax ID 9606, Species Homo sapiens, Chromosome NC\_000013.11} \\ 
\hline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 9445 & ITM2B & integral\_membrane\_protein\_2B & 48233205 & 48270356 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88930.1, EAX08788.1, EAX08789.1, EAX08790.1, EAX08791.1, Q9Y287.1, AAP97148.1, AAD40370.1, AAG49434.1, AAD45280.1, AAF66130.1, BAA91210.1, AAH00554.1, AAH16148.1, AAP35509.1, ADO22246.1, NP\_068839.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 5925 & RB1 & RB\_transcriptional\_corepressor\_1 & 48303750 & 48481889 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAA53483.1, AAA53484.1, AAA65735.1, AAA65736.1, AAA65737.1, AAA65738.1, AAA65739.1, AAA65740.1, AAA65741.1, AAA65742.1, AAA65743.1, AAA65744.1, AAA65745.1, AAB59466.1, AAB59467.1, AAB59468.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 10161 & LPAR6 & lysophosphatidic\_acid\_receptor\_6 & 48389570 & 48444668 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAL40065.1, AAN64134.1, EAX08796.1, P43657.3, BAD97109.1, BAG53764.1, XP\_047285975.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 1102 & RCBTB2 & RCC1\_and\_BTB\_domain\_containing\_protein\_2 & 48488962 & 48535894 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88928.1, CBX47529.1, O95199.1, BAD92780.1, BAG51149.1, BAG60659.1, NP\_001259.1, XP\_047286023.1, XP\_054230030.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 124903173 & LOC124903173 & uncharacterized\_LOC124903173 & 48504383 & 48506805 & - & NC\_000013.11 & XP\_047286780.1, XP\_047302191.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 57105 & CYSLTR2 & cysteinyl\_leukotriene\_receptor\_2 & 48653928 & 48711225 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAG17281.1, AAK69485.1, BAB16379.1, CAC69300.1, NP\_001295400.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 22862 & FNDC3A & fibronectin\_type\_III\_domain\_containing\_3A & 48975290 & 49209778 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9Y2H6.4, BAA76814.3, CAG44603.1, NP\_055738.3 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 2862 & MLNR & motilin\_receptor & 49220337 & 49222376 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAC26081.1, O43193.1, NP\_001498.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81602 & CDADC1 & cytidine\_and\_dCMP\_deaminase\_domain\_containing\_1 & 49247924 & 49293484 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9BWV3.1, XP\_054231027.1, XP\_054231032.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81617 & CAB39L & calcium\_binding\_protein\_39\_like & 49308649 & 49444063 & - & NC\_000013.11 & CAC37735.1, XP\_054231033.1, NP\_112187.2 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 107303344 & SETDB2-PHF11 & SETDB2-PHF11\_readthrough & 49444273 & 49528975 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AFD33305.1, NP\_001307656.1 \\
\hline 
%%% Now the "mice" group
\multicolumn{10}{|l|}{Tax ID 10090, Species Mus musculus, Chromosome NC\_000080.7} \\ 
\hline
10090 & Mus\_musculus & 14586 & Gfra2 &  glial\_cell\_line\_derived\_neurotrophic\_factor\_family\_receptor\_alpha\_2 & 71127546  &  71217279 & + & NC\_000080.7 & AAK97483.1, EDL35875.1, EDL35876.1, O08842.2, AAC53548.1, AAC82464.1, AAC82465.1, BAE23689.1, BAE28825.1, AAI38562.1, NP\_001289023.1, NP\_001289024.1, NP\_032141.2 \\
%10090 & Mus\_musculus & 675947 & Gm9195 &  predicted\_gene\_9195 & 72669099    & 72699093 & - & NC\_000080.7 & XP\_017171829.1 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{landscape} % end of landscape mode

\end{document}


As supplement to nice @Mico answer. For anyone who like to use tabularray instead of xltabular package. With it a wee bit shorter code is gotten but the command \SetCell[c=...]{...} ... in contrary to \multicolumn{...}{...}{...} is sensitive to settings of column where it started. This mean, that its text will appear if first spanned column is not hidden.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for a more-visible underscore symbol

\usepackage{pdflscape}    % For landscape-mode pages

%%% new code
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 


\NewColumnType{H}{Q[cmd={\setbox0=\vbox}, colsep=0pt]}% ljr: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16607


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape} % Start of landscape mode

\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
                ]{colspec = {| H H 
                             l | l | 
                             X[l, cmd={\renewcommand{\_}{\textunderscore\allowbreak}}] |
                             l | l | Q[c, mode=math] | 
                             H 
                             X[1.5, l] |},
                  row{1}  =  {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                  rowhead = 1,
                     }       
%% headers
    \toprule
TaxID   &  Species  & Gene ID   & 
Gene Symbol & Gene Name & Start & 
End & Strand    & Chr   & Accession \\
    \midrule
%% body of table
    &   &   \SetCell[c=8]{} Tax ID 9606, Species Homo sapiens, Chromosome NC\_000013.11    % it should star at first no hidden column
            \\*
    \midrule
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 9445 & ITM2B 
    & integral\_membrane\_protein\_2B 
        & 48233205 & 48270356 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88930.1, EAX08788.1, EAX08789.1, EAX08790.1, EAX08791.1, Q9Y287.1, AAP97148.1, AAD40370.1, AAG49434.1, AAD45280.1, AAF66130.1, BAA91210.1, AAH00554.1, AAH16148.1, AAP35509.1, ADO22246.1, NP\_068839.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 5925 & RB1 & RB\_transcriptional\_corepressor\_1 & 48303750 & 48481889 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAA53483.1, AAA53484.1, AAA65735.1, AAA65736.1, AAA65737.1, AAA65738.1, AAA65739.1, AAA65740.1, AAA65741.1, AAA65742.1, AAA65743.1, AAA65744.1, AAA65745.1, AAB59466.1, AAB59467.1, AAB59468.1 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 10161 & LPAR6 & lysophosphatidic\_acid\_receptor\_6 & 48389570 & 48444668 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAL40065.1, AAN64134.1, EAX08796.1, P43657.3, BAD97109.1, BAG53764.1, XP\_047285975.1 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 1102 & RCBTB2 & RCC1\_and\_BTB\_domain\_containing\_protein\_2 & 48488962 & 48535894 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88928.1, CBX47529.1, O95199.1, BAD92780.1, BAG51149.1, BAG60659.1, NP\_001259.1, XP\_047286023.1, XP\_054230030.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 124903173 & LOC124903173 & uncharacterized\_LOC124903173 & 48504383 & 48506805 & - & NC\_000013.11 & XP\_047286780.1, XP\_047302191.1 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 57105 & CYSLTR2 & cysteinyl\_leukotriene\_receptor\_2 & 48653928 & 48711225 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAG17281.1, AAK69485.1, BAB16379.1, CAC69300.1, NP\_001295400.1 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 22862 & FNDC3A & fibronectin\_type\_III\_domain\_containing\_3A & 48975290 & 49209778 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9Y2H6.4, BAA76814.3, CAG44603.1, NP\_055738.3 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 2862 & MLNR & motilin\_receptor & 49220337 & 49222376 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAC26081.1, O43193.1, NP\_001498.1 \\
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81602 & CDADC1 & cytidine\_and\_dCMP\_deaminase\_domain\_containing\_1 & 49247924 & 49293484 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9BWV3.1, XP\_054231027.1, XP\_054231032.1 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81617 & CAB39L & calcium\_binding\_protein\_39\_like & 49308649 & 49444063 & - & NC\_000013.11 & CAC37735.1, XP\_054231033.1, NP\_112187.2 \\

9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 107303344 & SETDB2-PHF11 & SETDB2-PHF11\_readthrough & 49444273 & 49528975 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AFD33305.1, NP\_001307656.1 \\
    \midrule
%%% Now the "mice" group
    &   &   \SetCell[c=8]{} Tax ID 10090, Species Mus musculus, Chromosome NC\_000080.7    % it should star at first no hidden column
            \\*
    \midrule
10090 & Mus\_musculus & 14586 & Gfra2 &  glial\_cell\_line\_derived\_neurotrophic\_factor\_family\_receptor\_alpha\_2 & 71127546  &  71217279 & + & NC\_000080.7 & AAK97483.1, EDL35875.1, EDL35876.1, O08842.2, AAC53548.1, AAC82464.1, AAC82465.1, BAE23689.1, BAE28825.1, AAI38562.1, NP\_001289023.1, NP\_001289024.1, NP\_032141.2 \\

%10090 & Mus\_musculus & 675947 & Gm9195 &  predicted\_gene\_9195 & 72669099    & 72699093 & - & NC\_000080.7 & XP\_017171829.1 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{landscape} % end of landscape mode

\end{document}



Here is the code with some tweaks which I believe should serve your purpose:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % To enable landscape pages
\usepackage{adjustbox} % To adjust table width
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better table lines
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables spanning multiple pages
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=20.0mm, right=20.0mm, top=15.0mm, bottom=20.0mm]{geometry} % To control page margins

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\_{\textunderscore\allowbreak}
\raggedright

\begin{landscape} % Start of landscape page

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % Set left margin for longtable
\setlength\LTright{0pt} % Set right margin for longtable

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|>{\raggedright}p{0.175\textwidth}|c|c|c|c|>{\raggedright}p{0.300\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{TaxID} & \textbf{Species} & \textbf{GeneID} & \textbf{Gene Symbol} & \textbf{Gene Name} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Strand} & \textbf{Chr} & \textbf{Accession} \tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{r}{\textit{Continued to next page}}\tabularnewline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 9445 & ITM2B & integral\_membrane\_protein\_2B & 48233205 & 48270356 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88930.1, EAX08788.1, EAX08789.1, EAX08790.1, EAX08791.1, Q9Y287.1, AAP97148.1, AAD40370.1, AAG49434.1, AAD45280.1, AAF66130.1, BAA91210.1, AAH00554.1, AAH16148.1, AAP35509.1, ADO22246.1, NP\_068839.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 5925 & RB1 & RB\_transcriptional\_corepressor\_1 & 48303750 & 48481889 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAA53483.1, AAA53484.1, AAA65735.1, AAA65736.1, AAA65737.1, AAA65738.1, AAA65739.1, AAA65740.1, AAA65741.1, AAA65742.1, AAA65743.1, AAA65744.1, AAA65745.1, AAB59466.1, AAB59467.1, AAB59468.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 10161 & LPAR6 & lysophosphatidic\_acid\_receptor\_6 & 48389570 & 48444668 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAL40065.1, AAN64134.1, EAX08796.1, P43657.3, BAD97109.1, BAG53764.1, XP\_047285975.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 1102 & RCBTB2 & RCC1\_and\_BTB\_domain\_containing\_protein\_2 & 48488962 & 48535894 & - & NC\_000013.11 & AAP88928.1, CBX47529.1, O95199.1, BAD92780.1, BAG51149.1, BAG60659.1, NP\_001259.1, XP\_047286023.1, XP\_054230030.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 124903173 & LOC124903173 & uncharacterized\_LOC124903173 & 48504383 & 48506805 & - & NC\_000013.11 & XP\_047286780.1, XP\_047302191.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 57105 & CYSLTR2 & cysteinyl\_leukotriene\_receptor\_2 & 48653928 & 48711225 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAG17281.1, AAK69485.1, BAB16379.1, CAC69300.1, NP\_001295400.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 22862 & FNDC3A & fibronectin\_type\_III\_domain\_containing\_3A & 48975290 & 49209778 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9Y2H6.4, BAA76814.3, CAG44603.1, NP\_055738.3 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 2862 & MLNR & motilin\_receptor & 49220337 & 49222376 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AAC26081.1, O43193.1, NP\_001498.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81602 & CDADC1 & cytidine\_and\_dCMP\_deaminase\_domain\_containing\_1 & 49247924 & 49293484 & + & NC\_000013.11 & Q9BWV3.1, XP\_054231027.1, XP\_054231032.1 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 81617 & CAB39L & calcium\_binding\_protein\_39\_like & 49308649 & 49444063 & - & NC\_000013.11 & CAC37735.1, XP\_054231033.1, NP\_112187.2 \tabularnewline
9606 & Homo\_sapiens & 107303344 & SETDB2-PHF11 & SETDB2-PHF11\_readthrough & 49444273 & 49528975 & + & NC\_000013.11 & AFD33305.1, NP\_001307656.1
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape} % End of landscape page

\endgroup

\end{document}

Summary of changes:

Use p (paragraph) type columns with specified widths for your very wide columns.
Use \raggedright in the above columns for better visualization of information.
Allow linebreaks at underscores.
Added running footer for better navigation.

You can adjust the parameters as seem fit for your purposes. You are the final decision-maker in this respect.




Allowing line breaks after _ (underscore) symbols should be allowed in column 5, but probably not in column 10.

@Mico, Thanks. I left that issue to the OP. However, he may struggle to add the relevant control to the column specifiers. Let's hear if he is asking for more.

Please see my updated answer for a method to redefine \_ as \textunderscore\allowbreak programmatically. This allows making the redefinition apply to one column only.
